# Are there good Java libraries that facilitate building command-line applications?

Tags: java, shell, command-line, interactive

I need to write a simple command-line application in Java.  It would be nice to use a library that takes care of parsing commands and takes care of things like flags and optional/mandatory parameters...

**UPDATE**

Something that has built-in TAB completion would be particularly great.

Comment: Typically CLI means your app takes arguments from the command line to determine in what way to run.   Based on your update, do you mean you want to have an interactive shell-style process inside your java application? (like irb?)

Comment: yes i do actually... you are correct

Comment: irb is interactive ruby.  I think you would benefit from re-asking your question without using the phrase "command-line" or "cli".   Maybe "Are there libraries to create an interactive shell in java?" and give example usage of your app for clarity.

Comment: [Spring Shell](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-shell) looks pretty good.

Comment: This is a good question that deserves to be on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I've used the [Apache Commons CLI library](http://commons.apache.org/cli/) for command-line argument parsing.  It's fairly easy to use and has [reasonably good documentation](http://commons.apache.org/cli/introduction.html).

Which library you choose probably comes down to which style of options you prefer ("--gnu-style" or "-javac-style").

Answer (score 21):

[JLine](https://github.com/jline/jline3/) looks helpful.

> JLine is a Java library for handling console input. It is similar in functionality to BSD editline and GNU readline. People familiar with the readline/editline capabilities for modern shells (such as bash and tcsh) will find most of the command editing features of JLine to be familiar.

And it does list tab completion in its [features](https://github.com/jline/jline3/wiki).

Comment: +1; readline was the first thing that came to mind for me, and this seems to be the Java equivalent.

Answer (score 8):

As you're searching for a library that eases developing an interactive shell application, I'd suggest [Cliche](http://code.google.com/p/cliche/).

Comment: `cliche` is super simple yet very powerful. I recommend it.

Comment: will it support password masking

Answer (score 4):

In our company we are using [JewelCli](http://jewelcli.sourceforge.net/) that uses an annotated Java interface definition to describe the Command Line Interface in a declarative style.

Light and simple to use, I'll recommend it.

Comment: No Tab-completion for jewelcli, it's just a basic (but great) command line arguments parser.

Answer (score 3):

I have used the [Java Simple Argument Parser](http://www.martiansoftware.com/jsap/) extensively.  It handles all sorts of option types, has a well-designed and library (including the option to write custom parsers), and provides good documentation both in the JavaDocs and [online](http://www.martiansoftware.com/jsap/doc/).

I think your desire for tab completion would be taken care of by the shell rather than the command-line parsing library.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Java port of GNU getopt library](http://www.urbanophile.com/arenn/hacking/download.html) for command line parsing. For command editing and TAB completion there is JLine (as mmyers has already recommended).

Answer (score 1):

It's also worth looking at [--jopt-simple](http://pholser.github.com/jopt-simple/).

It 'attempts to honor the command line option syntaxes of POSIX getopt() and GNU getopt_long().' 
It seems to have some community traction, notably being the command line parsing lib of choice for the [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/).

Also, as Brett mentioned, tab completion is typically provided by your shell - you would write shell functions to provide that desired functionality.

p.s. Sorry for the duplicate answer, but this question is almost identical to [Java library for parsing command-line parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200054/java-library-for-parsing-command-line-parameters/)

Answer (score 1):

I tried a few libraries and ended up using [argparse4j](http://argparse4j.sourceforge.net). It's a really nice Java port of Python's [argparse](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html).

Answer (score 0):

I have used [JSAP](http://www.martiansoftware.com/jsap/). I have found it to be stable and well documented.

I am not sure I understand what you mean by "built-in TAB completion". Can you elaborate.