# Is it possible in Java to show the results of a for loop in only one Output?

Tags: java, for-loop, countdown

I have a little code that displays a countdown in the console.

```
for(int i = this.roundTimerMinute; i > -1; i--)
    {
        for(int j = this.roundTimerSeconds; j > 0; j--)
        {

            if( j < 10)
            {
                System.out.println(i + ":0" + j);
            }
            else if(!(i == 0 && j == 60) && (j < 56 && i == 1))
            {
                System.out.println(i + ":" + j);
            }
            else if(i == 0 && j != 60)
            {
                System.out.println(i + ":" + j);
            }

            if(i == 0 && j == 60)
            {
                System.out.println("1:00");
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    }
```

Currently the output is something like:

```
1:55
1:54
1:53 
.
.
.
```

Is is possible to display the whole countdown in only one line. Not consecutively but the new println() overdisplays the old one like this:

```
1:55 (this display is overridden 1 seconds later by 1:54 and so on)
```

I would appreciate any help.
Thanks

MageD

Edit: So it works with the /r command but only in the CMD of Windows itself. Maybe its a bug or so, but it answers my question. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use `print` rather than `println` and add a `"\r"` at the end of each output:

e.g. `System.out.println(i + ":0" + j + "\r");`

When you use `println` it does 2 things: moves onto the next line (line feed) and returns the cursor to the start of the line (carriage return). Think of it like a typewriter :-)

If you manually print `"\r"` (just the carriage return) without advancing to the next line then the next thing you print will overwrite the previous contents of the line.

Comment: I just tried that. I does not work for me. It still displays each number under each other. Just like with System.out.println()

Comment: Are you running your code from the command line or from within your editor/IDE?

Comment: I use Eclipse as IDE. So the code is running in the IDE

Comment: Ok, it's possible Eclipse's output window isn't handling the `\r` correctly. Are you on a recent Eclipse? This used to be a bug in Eclipse but it was meant to be fixed in the release from June last year.

Comment: I use Version: Luna Release (4.4.0). I can try this in the cmd console.

Comment: Cool, give it a go from the command line, or try Eclipse Mars

Answer (score 0):

You could try this: [Java: Updating text in the command-line without a new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573123/java-updating-text-in-the-command-line-without-a-new-line)

You can use a "\r" to Carriage Return without using \n which is a New line. The carriage return should put you back at the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 0):

you want to write something to your terminal (like `1:59`), and then erase it and over-write it with something else (like `1:58`) ?  If so, then no there's no easy way to do that with regular `System.out` methods.  You need to have knowledge of the [control characters](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/research/gpc/MSim/vona/terminal/VT100_Escape_Codes.html) for your OS and terminal type, or possibly use a library such as one of those suggested [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0047.html) (I've not tried any of them, they're just what Google returned me).

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a [Curses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)) library.

> Most implementations of curses use a database that can describe the capabilities of thousands of different terminals. There are a few implementations, such as PDCurses, which use specialized device drivers rather than a terminal database. Most implementations use terminfo; some use termcap.

There are a few Java Curses libraries described in 
[What's a good Java, curses-like, library for terminal applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439799/whats-a-good-java-curses-like-library-for-terminal-applications)

It may seem like much, but otherwise you'll need a terminal capabilities database of your own for that one function.