# Updating java Console without printing new line

Tags: java, console

So, basically what I want to do is have a percentage. So it goes up 0%, 1% and so on but, instead of having it all printed, I want the %1 percent replaced with 2%. So I know how to do the basic `for` loop but I don't know how to use `\r` or `\b` because in my compiler all I'm getting is it printing it all in one line.

```
package test;

public class est
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {       
        for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++ )
        {
            System.out.print("\rPercent = " + i + "%");
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
Percent = 0%
Percent = 1%
```

...

```
Percent = 99%
Percent = 100%
```

So it prints 100 lines; but I only want that information on one line.

Comment: \r should work, some terminals do not support it though.

Comment: see https://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439799/whats-a-good-java-curses-like-library-for-terminal-applications

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's a good Java, curses-like, library for terminal applications?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439799/whats-a-good-java-curses-like-library-for-terminal-applications)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is: System.out is not an appropriate basis when you strive to provide "enhanced user experience". Maybe in this case, as you can use \r to delete **on the same line**. But as soon as you need / want to do a **println()** that context is fixed; and you can't change it anymore.

And even then: "going back" and erasing information can't be done in a way that would work on each platform.

You have three options:

- simply accept it. In the real world, command line output is often ugly and most people accept that.
- look into "curses" based libraries, as those allow for "placing" and "resetting" your "cursor". But I actually can't say how platform independent those libraries are.
- go down the full nine yards and consider creating a real Guide. But of course, that is the most expensive solution to your problem.

Comment: _System.out is not an appropriate basis when you strive to provide "enhanced user experience"_... is there an appropriate basis?

Comment: so one can not update console, or replace text in console?

Comment: sorry, that is because I was confused by what you were saying. I meant to Re-Upvote it, but got sidetracked with a new question. I just upvoted now.   :D

Comment: Is there any libraries that have a console built into a jframe which I could you to go about creating a rogue like?

Answer (score 4):

I tried using '\r' in the sysout and it worked for me in Intellij Idea console & running it from terminal of mac osx.

```
 public static void main(String[] a) throws InterruptedException {
    int progress = 10;
    for(progress = 10; progress<=100; progress+=10) {
        System.out.print("\rPercent = " + (progress) + "%");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    }
}
```

You may want to give it a try.
However, I strongly believe it will be dependent upon the underlying console and OS.

Comment: this did not work on eclipse when I tried to run it, it printed individual lines. However, when I ran it in terminal, it worked great. Nice Job.

Answer (score 2):

For eclipse you need to configure the console to interpret the Ascii charaters like so

[image]