# Update Java multiple-line console output without adding new lines

Tags: java, console-application

I just came to the issue to update java console multiple-line output. What I want to achieve is like this output, and dynamically update the progress text and progress bar without adding new lines.

```
Progress: 24/100
[>>>>>>>                      ] 24%
```

I saw there are some similar [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43600639/updating-java-console-without-printing-new-line) (`like using System.out.print()` with `\r`), but mostly for single line.

I'm curious is there a way to achieve the same for multiple lines?

Thanks.