# Rewrite content in terminal as basic as possible (JAVA)

Tags: java, terminal

I want to be able to output some simple graphic in the terminal. To do so, I have to rewrite the characters in the terminal. I know that this is possible in C, but I don't know how to do it in JAVA.

So, to clarify what I want, here an example:

. . . . . .

. . . . . .

. . . . . .

. . . . . .

. . . . . .

. . . . . .

If this is the terminal and I want to put an asterisk at the 2nd position in the 2nd line, I want to overwrite everything and the terminal should only display:

. . . . . .

. * . . . .

. . . . . .

. . . . . .

. . . . . .

. . . . . .

How can I accomplish this in an as simple JAVA-Code as possible (preferably without special libraries).

Thanks for the time!

(Essentially, I want to program the game of Life with a visualization in the terminal)

Comment: let us know what you have tried

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573123/java-updating-text-in-the-command-line-without-a-new-line

Comment: You are probably looking for something like `ncurses` but in Java: https://github.com/mabe02/lanterna

Comment: Googling ANSI escape codes would probably help, if you're in a console which supports it.