# (Java) Trying to make a basic text-based progress bar, but output is inconsistent

Tags: java, progress-bar

Just trying to work out why the output in the console only updates every 10  or so iterations of the loop and not consistently.

````
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        for(int i = 0; i <=100;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(i+"% complete");
            Thread.sleep(500);
            System.out.print("\r");
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: Thanks, running it normally in Netbeans. It will output 10% then wait for long and print 34% and so on. How would i omit the linefeed?

Comment: Okay, but then it appends the output.

Comment: for(int i = 0; i <=100;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(i+"% complete");
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
OUTPUTS:
0% complete
1% complete
etc

Comment: So, instead of appending the output each iteration of the loop, i want it to "update" the output every 0.5 seconds, but the output updates only when the console is refreshed which i don't think is a coding error.

Comment: Okay, i changed to println, still only appends the output. I think the error is not related to the code, but thanks for assisting.

Comment: Wait, by "update the output, not append" do you mean something like replacing the current value in the console with the new value?

Comment: I think I understood your issue now. Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573123/java-updating-text-in-the-command-line-without-a-new-line) what you want?

Comment: You probably just need a `System.out.flush();` after printing the percentage.  Most terminals and command windows buffer their output.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps try replacing `System.out.print("\r");` with `System.out.print("\n");` to ensure the buffer flushes.

If the `\r` is important, you can call `System.out.flush()` at the end to ensure the text is printed to output.

Comment: Thanks, the \r is important and sadly System.out.flush() doesn't resolve it. I think the error is to do with my pc or the Netbeans IDE. No worries.