# Pad digits until string is 8 chars long in java?

Tags: java, string, hex, padding

i was reading and couldn't find quite the snippet. I am looking for a function that takes in a string and left pads zeros (0) until the entire string is 8 digits long. All the other snippets i find only lets the integer control how much to pad and not how much to pad until the entire string is x digits long. in java.

Example

> BC238 => 000BC289
>   4 => 00000004

etc thanks.

Comment: To make a piece of hex a valid 8 char long piece of hex code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Left padding a String with Zeros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469717/left-padding-a-string-with-zeros)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you're starting with a string that you know is <= 8 characters long, you can do something like this:

```
s = "00000000".substring(0, 8 - s.length()) + s;
```

Actually, this works as well:

```
s = "00000000".substring(s.length()) + s;
```

If you're not sure that `s` is at most 8 characters long, you need to test it before using either of the above (or use `Math.min(8, s.length())` or be prepared to catch an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`).

If you're starting with an integer and want to convert it to hex with padding, you can do this:

```
String s = String.format("%08x", Integer.valueOf(val));
```

Answer (score 5):

```
org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.leftPad(String str, int size, char padChar)
```

You can take a look [here](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#leftPad%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20char%29)

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
s = (s.length()) < 8 ? ("00000000".substring(s.length()) + s) : s;
```

or

```
s = "00000000".substring(Math.min(8, s.length())) + s;
```

I prefer using an existing library method though, such as a method from Apache Commons `StringUtils`, or `String.format(...)`.  The intent of your code is clearer if you use a library method, assuming it is has a sensible name.

Comment: I like this; the substring calculation is simpler than in my solution.

Answer (score 1):

The lazy way is to use something like: Right("00000000" + yourstring, 8) with simple implementations of the Right function available here: http://geekswithblogs.net/congsuco/archive/2005/07/07/45607.aspx