# Convert Integer to Hex String

Tags: java

i have an Integer value and  i want to convert it on Hex.

i do this:

```
private short getCouleur(Integer couleur, HSSFWorkbook classeur) {
if (null == couleur) {
    return WHITE.index;
} else {
    HSSFPalette palette = classeur.getCustomPalette();
    String hexa = Integer.toHexString(couleur);

    byte r = Integer.valueOf(hexa.substring(0, 2), 16).byteValue();
    byte g = Integer.valueOf(hexa.substring(2, 4), 16).byteValue();
    byte b = Integer.valueOf(hexa.substring(4, 6), 16).byteValue();

    palette.setColorAtIndex((short) 65, r, g, b);

    return (short) 65;
}
}
```

In output i have this:

**couleur**: 65331

**Hexa**: FF33

**hexa.substring(0, 2)**: FF

**hexa.substring(2, 4)**: 33

**hexa.substring(4, 6)**:

**r**: -1

**g**: 51

**b**: error message

> error message: String index out of range: 6

Thx.

Comment: already answered here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258415/how-to-get-hex-value-from-integer-in-java

Comment: @radai it's not the same problem

Comment: @AlexeyOdintsov I already use

Comment: You must pad the hex string before extracting the byte arrays. Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446863/pad-digits-until-string-is-8-chars-long-in-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to split an `int` into three bytes (R, G, B).
If so, then you can do this by simply shifting the bits in the integer:

```
byte r = (byte)((couleur >> 16) & 0x000000ff);
byte g = (byte)((couleur >> 8) & 0x000000ff);
byte b = (byte)(couleur & 0x000000ff);
```

That's much more efficient. You don't have to do it through conversion to `String`.

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to byte

Answer (score 6):

you can call the method in JDK.

```
String result = Integer.toHexString(131);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are assuming that the hex string will be six digits long.

try `String.format ("%06d", Integer.toHexString(couleur));`

to pad it with zeros if less than 6 digits longs