# String is immutable. What exactly is the meaning?

Tags: java, string, immutability

I wrote the following code on immutable Strings.

```
public class ImmutableStrings {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        testmethod();
    }

    private static void testmethod() {
        String a = "a";
        System.out.println("a 1-->" + a);
        a = "ty";
        System.out.println("a 2-->" + a);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
a 1-->a  
a 2-->ty
```

Here the value of variable `a` has been changed (while many say that contents of the immutable objects cannot be changed). But what exactly does one mean by saying **`String` is immutable**? Could you please clarify this topic for me?

source : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: immutable in the sense of memory. It creates new objects every time you create strings or assign a new string/change the value. That's why it is advisable to be careful when using strings. Charbuffer would be better.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93091/why-cant-strings-be-mutable-in-java-and-net. Take a look at this for better explanation.

Comment: String is immutable  ( once created can not be changed ) object  . The object created as a String is stored in the  Constant String Pool.
Every immutable object in Java is thread safe ,that implies String is also thread safe . String can not be used by two threads simultaneously.
String  once assigned can not be changed.

Answer (score 472, accepted):

Before proceeding further with the fuss of *immutability*, let's just take a look into the `String` class and its functionality a little before coming to any conclusion.

This is how `String` works:

```
String str = "knowledge";
```

This, as usual, creates a string containing `"knowledge"` and assigns it a reference `str`. Simple enough? Lets perform some more functions:

```
 String s = str;     // assigns a new reference to the same string "knowledge"
```

Lets see how the below statement works:

```
  str = str.concat(" base");
```

This appends a string `" base"` to `str`. But wait, how is this possible, since `String` objects are immutable? Well to your surprise, it is.

When the above statement is executed, the VM takes the value of `String str`, i.e. `"knowledge"` and appends `" base"`, giving us the value `"knowledge base"`. Now, since `String`s are immutable, the VM can't assign this value to `str`, so it creates a new `String` object, gives it a value `"knowledge base"`, and gives it a reference `str`.

An important point to note here is that, while the `String` object is immutable, **its reference variable is not.** So that's why, in the above example, the reference was made to refer to a newly formed `String` object.

At this point in the example above, we have two `String` objects: the first one we created with value `"knowledge"`, pointed to by `s`, and the second one `"knowledge base"`, pointed to by `str`. But, technically, we have three `String` objects, the third one being the literal `"base"` in the `concat` statement.

## Important Facts about String and Memory usage

What if we didn't have another reference `s` to `"knowledge"`? We would have lost that `String`. However, it still would have existed, but would be considered lost due to having no references.
Look at one more example below

```
String s1 = "java";
s1.concat(" rules");
System.out.println("s1 refers to "+s1);  // Yes, s1 still refers to "java"
```

**What's happening:**

1. The first line is pretty straightforward: create a new `String` `"java"` and refer `s1` to it.
2. Next, the VM creates another new `String` `"java rules"`, but nothing
   refers to it. So, the second `String` is instantly lost. We can't reach
   it.

The reference variable `s1` still refers to the original `String` `"java"`.

Almost every method, applied to a `String` object in order to modify it, creates new `String` object. So, where do these `String` objects go? Well, *these exist in memory, and one of the key goals of any programming language is to make efficient use of memory.*

As applications grow, *it's very common for `String` literals to occupy large area of memory, which can even cause redundancy.* So, in order to make Java more efficient, **the JVM sets aside a special area of memory called the "String constant pool".**

When the compiler sees a `String` literal, it looks for the `String` in the pool. If a match is found, the reference to the new literal is directed to the existing `String` and no new `String` object is created. The existing `String` simply has one more reference. Here comes the point of making `String` objects immutable:

In the `String` constant pool, a `String` object is likely to have one or many references. *If several references point to same `String` without even knowing it, it would be bad if one of the references modified that `String` value. That's why `String` objects are immutable.*

Well, now you could say, *what if someone overrides the functionality of `String` class?* That's the reason that **the `String` class is marked `final`** so that nobody can override the behavior of its methods.

Comment: "If several references point to same String without even knowing it, it would be bad if one of the references modified that String value. That's why String objects are immutable." AND "what if someone overrides the functionality of String class? That's the reason that the String class is marked final so that nobody can override the behavior of its methods."
Good explanation!

Comment: This changed my life :- "An important point to note here is that, while the String object is immutable, its reference variable is not. So that's why, in the above example, the reference was made to refer to a newly formed String object."

Comment: @roger_that Excellent, can you add String a = new String("a"); immutable concepts as well.

Comment: String s1 = "hello"; String s2 = "world"; String s3 = s1+s2; String s4 = "helloworld"; System.out.println(s3 == s4); here why it is showing false?

Comment: What an answer ! - This was the key statement - "An important point to note here is that, while the String object is immutable, its reference variable is not". Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 177):

String is immutable means that you cannot change the object itself, but you can change the reference to the object.

When you execute `a = "ty"`, you are actually changing the reference of `a` to a new object created by the String literal `"ty"`.

Changing an object means to use its methods to change one of its fields (or the fields are public and not final, so that they can be updated from outside without accessing them via methods), for example:

```
Foo x = new Foo("the field");
x.setField("a new field");
System.out.println(x.getField()); // prints "a new field"
```

While in an immutable class (declared as final, to prevent modification via inheritance)(its methods cannot modify its fields, and also the fields are always private and recommended to be final), for example String, you cannot change the current String but you can return a new String, i.e:

```
String s = "some text";
s.substring(0,4);
System.out.println(s); // still printing "some text"
String a = s.substring(0,4);
System.out.println(a); // prints "some"
```

Comment: your example with String was very much required. Thanks

Answer (score 19):

You're changing what `a` *refers to*. Try this:

```
String a="a";
System.out.println("a 1-->"+a);
String b=a;
a="ty";
System.out.println("a 2-->"+a);
System.out.println("b  -->"+b);
```

You will see that the *object* to which `a` and then `b` refers has not changed.

If you want to prevent your code from changing which object `a` refers to, try:

```
final String a="a";
```

Comment: String a=new String("a");       Now, I have created object 'a'. If I try to modify the value in this object a, it wont be possible ?

Comment: That's true. `String a = "a";` means essentially the same thing as `String a = new String("a");` in Java (except for string interning).

Comment: One last doubt. Now I understood that I was changeing the reference, and this is allowed. What exactly is not allowed, when we say String is immutable? Changing the contents of the object !!! Can you give example of this ?? I mean what cannot be done with string

Comment: The `String` class is immutable because it has *no methods that can change its contents*. Contrast this with `StringBuilder`, which has methods such as `.append()` and `.delete()`, and is not immutable.

Comment: @Ajj see my answer for the example you are looking for :)

Comment: I believe you can change the value of String using reflection. In the sense that they are not truly immutable. Not entirely sure though.

Answer (score 5):

A string is a `char[]` containing a series of [UTF-16 code units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16), an `int` offset into that array, and an `int` length.

For example.

```
String s
```

It creates space for a string reference.  Assigning copies references around but does not modify the objects to which those references refer.

You should also be aware that

```
new String(s)
```

doesn't really do anything useful.  It merely creates another instance backed by the same array, offset, and length as `s`.  There is very rarely a reason to do this so it is considered bad practice by most Java programmers.

Java double quoted strings like `"my string"` are really references to [interned](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) `String` instances so `"bar"` is a reference to the same String instance regardless of how many times it appears in your code.

---

The "hello" creates one instance that is pooled, and the `new String(...)` creates a non-pooled instance. Try `System.out.println(("hello" == "hello") + "," + (new String("hello") == "hello") + "," + (new String("hello") == new String("hello")));` and you should see `true,false,false`

Answer (score 4):

immutable means you can't not change the value of the same referance.every time you required to create new referance means new memory location.
ex:

```
String str="abc";
str="bcd";
```

here, in the above code ,in the memory there are 2 blocks for storing the value.the first for value "abc" and second for "bcd".the second value is not replace to first value.

this is call the immutable.

Comment: This doesn't answer OP because immutability has to do with modification of a `String` value. But here you simply showing two different string literals and assigning to same reference.

Answer (score 3):

In your example, the variable `a` is just a reference to an instance of a string object.  When you say `a = "ty"`, you are not actually changing the string object, but rather pointing the reference at an entirely different instance of the string class.

Answer (score 3):

see here

```
class ImmutableStrings {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        testmethod();
    }

    private static void testmethod() {
    String a="a";
    System.out.println("a 1-->"+a);
    System.out.println("a 1 address-->"+a.hashCode());

    a = "ty";
    System.out.println("a 2-->"+a);

       System.out.println("a 2 address-->"+a.hashCode());
    }
}
```

output:

```
a 1-->a
a 1 address-->97
a 2-->ty
a 2 address-->3717
```

This indicates that whenever you are modifying the content of immutable string object `a` a new object will be created. i.e you are not allowed to change the content of immutable object. that's why the address are different for both the object.

Comment: `a = "ty";` is the new object in heap. right? what will happen to `String a ="a";` ?

Answer (score 2):

You are not changing the object in the assignment statement, you *replace* one immutable object with another one. Object `String("a")` does not change to `String("ty")`, it gets discarded, and a *reference* to `ty` gets written into `a` in its stead.

In contrast, `StringBuffer` represents a *mutable* object. You can do this:

```
StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer("Hello");
System.out.writeln(b);
b.append(", world!");
System.out.writeln(b);
```

Here, you did not re-assign `b`: it still points to the same object, but the *content* of that object has changed.

Answer (score 2):

You are actually getting a reference to a new string, the string itself is not being changed as it is immutable.  This is relevant.

See

[Immutable objects on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object#Java)

Answer (score 2):

An immutable object is an object whose state cannot be modified after it is created.

So `a = "ABC"` <-- immutable object. "a" holds reference to the object.
And, `a = "DEF"` <-- another immutable object, "a" holds reference to it now.

Once you assign a string object, that object can not be changed in memory.

In summary, what you did is to change the reference of "a" to a new string object.

Answer (score 2):

```
String S1="abc";
S1.concat("xyz");
System.out.println("S1 is", + S1);
String S2=S1.concat("def");
System.out.println("S2 is", + S2);
```

This shows that once a string object is create it cannot be changed. EveryTime you need to create new and put in another String. S

Answer (score 2):

I think the following code clears the difference:

```
String A = new String("Venugopal");
String B = A;

A = A +"mitul";

System.out.println("A is " + A);
System.out.println("B is " + B);

StringBuffer SA = new StringBuffer("Venugopal");
StringBuffer SB = SA;

SA = SA.append("mitul");

System.out.println("SA is " + SA);
System.out.println("SB is " + SB);
```

Answer (score 2):

Java `String` is immutable, `String` will Store the value in the form of object. so if u assign the value `String a="a";` it will create an object and the value is stored in that and again if you are assigning value `a="ty"` means it will create an another object store the value in that, if you want to understand clearly, check the `has code` for the `String`.

Answer (score 1):

Only the reference is changing. First `a` was referencing to the string "a", and later you changed it to "ty". The string "a" remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `a` refers first to `"a"`, and then to `"ty"`. You're not mutating any `String` instance; you're just changing which `String` instance `a` refers to. For example, this:

```
String a = "a";
String b = a; // b refers to the same String as a
a = "b"; // a now refers to a different instance
System.out.println(b);
```

prints "a", because we never mutate the `String` instance that `b` points to.

Answer (score 1):

If some object `bar` holds a reference to a mutable object `foo` *and encapsulates some of its state in mutable aspects of `foo`'s state*, that will allow code which can change those aspects of `foo` to change the corresponding aspects of `bar`'s state *without actually touching `bar` or even knowing of its existence*.  Generally, this means that objects which encapsulate their own state using mutable objects must ensure that no references to those objects are exposed to any code which might unexpectedly mutate them.  By contrast, if `bar` holds a reference to an object `moo` and only uses immutable aspects of `moo` *other than identity* to encapsulate its state, then `bar` can freely expose `moo` to outside code without worrying about anything the outside code might do to it.

Answer (score 1):

Hope the below code would clarify your doubts :

```
public static void testString() {
    String str = "Hello";
    System.out.println("Before String Concat: "+str);
    str.concat("World");
    System.out.println("After String Concat: "+str);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("Hello");
    System.out.println("Before StringBuffer Append: "+sb);
    sb.append("World");
    System.out.println("After StringBuffer Append: "+sb);
}
```

Before String Concat: Hello
After  String Concat: Hello
Before StringBuffer Append: Hello
After StringBuffer Append: HelloWorld

Comment: It would have been better if you added some explanation to it rather than just writing some code

Comment: I can see what he tries to do here, Showing the String 'str' is not changing (or should i said Adding) to HelloWorld. but when you using the StringBuffer it does change. anyway, it's just show that Strings are Immutables.

Answer (score 1):

String is immutable it means that,the content of the String Object can't be change, once it is created. If you want to modify the content then you can go for StringBuffer/StringBuilder instead of String. StringBuffer and StringBuilder are mutable classes.

Answer (score 1):

Probably every answer provided above is right, but my answer is specific to use of `hashCode()` method, to prove the points like, String... once created can't be modified and modifications will results in new value at different memory location.

```
public class ImmutabilityTest {

    private String changingRef = "TEST_STRING";

    public static void main(String a[]) {

        ImmutabilityTest dn = new ImmutabilityTest();

        System.out.println("ChangingRef for TEST_STRING OLD : "
                + dn.changingRef.hashCode());

        dn.changingRef = "NEW_TEST_STRING";
        System.out.println("ChangingRef for NEW_TEST_STRING : "
                + dn.changingRef.hashCode());

        dn.changingRef = "TEST_STRING";
        System.out.println("ChangingRef for TEST_STRING BACK : "
                + dn.changingRef.hashCode());

        dn.changingRef = "NEW_TEST_STRING";
        System.out.println("ChangingRef for NEW_TEST_STRING BACK : "
                + dn.changingRef.hashCode());

        String str = new String("STRING1");
        System.out.println("String Class STRING1 : " + str.hashCode());

        str = new String("STRING2");
        System.out.println("String Class STRING2 : " + str.hashCode());

        str = new String("STRING1");
        System.out.println("String Class STRING1 BACK : " + str.hashCode());

        str = new String("STRING2");
        System.out.println("String Class STRING2 BACK : " + str.hashCode());

    }
}
```

## OUTPUT

```
ChangingRef for TEST_STRING OLD : 247540830
ChangingRef for NEW_TEST_STRING : 970356767
ChangingRef for TEST_STRING BACK : 247540830
ChangingRef for NEW_TEST_STRING BACK : 970356767
String Class STRING1 : -1163776448
String Class STRING2 : -1163776447
String Class STRING1 BACK : -1163776448
String Class STRING2 BACK : -1163776447
```