# Java Enhanced For Loop - Editing Original Array Values

Tags: java, memory-management, for-loop

I'd like to know, in detail, how the Enhanced For Loop works in Java (assuming i do get how the basic usage of this loop is and how it works in general).

Given the following code:

```
String[] a = {"dog", "cat", "turtle"};

for (String s : a) {
  out.println("String: " + s);
  s = in.readLine("New String? ");
}
```

It doesn't actually modify the original list 'a'.
Why not? How memory Management works? Isn't 's' a reference to the same memory cell of 'a[i]'?

I read on the oracle documentation that enhanced for loops can't be used to remove elements from the original array, it makes sense. Is it the same for modifying values?

Thanks in advance

Comment: String is immutable.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8798424/112500

Comment: `s` is a variable that contains a reference to the element of the container.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Isn't 's' a reference to the same memory cell of 'a[i]'?

Originally, yes.  But then `in.readLine` produces a reference to a new String object, which you then use to overwrite `s`.  But only `s` is overwritten, not the underlying string, nor the reference in the array.

Comment: @Oliver, Do you mean that the reference s starts refering to some other string object rather than a[i] when we so s = new String ("X")?

Answer (score 5):

`s` is a local variable that points to the `String` instance. It is not associated with `a[i]`, they just happen to have the same value initially.

Answer (score 3):

You can only write

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  out.println("String: " + a[i]);
  a[i] = in.readLine("New String? ");
}
```

You can't use for-each loops to modify the original collection or array.

Comment: You made clear the last point that was still blurry. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you want to remove() or change entries for a List, you have to use an Iterator explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Think in `s` like an *address* to an object. The thing here is that `s` is pointing out to a certain value of the array when using the for loop. When you reassing `s` inside the loop is just happen that `s` points out to another value but the original value of the array is not modified as you are only changing the *address* `s` is pointing to.

```
String[] a = {"dog", "cat", "turtle"};

for (String s : a) {
  //s --> "dog"
  out.println("String: " + s);
  s = in.readLine("New String? ");
  //s --> the new string the user inputs
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. What i was missing is the fact that the readLine is returning a new address.

Comment: If your question is answered feel free to upvote and accept an answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

For every iteration String s initially references to corresponding String object in String a[]. But it is then referenced to another String object that is returned by in.readLine().