# java.lang.NullPointerException upon access to an Imageview[] array - Javafx

Tags: java, arrays, image, nullpointerexception, javafx-8

I'm sorry if this seems trivial to you all, but I am still learning and I have looked through articles and tried several techniques...I could create each card image separately, but I need to learn how to do this. I am throwing a java.lang.NullPointerException on this bit of code:

```
setCardBack.setImage(new Image("image/cardDown.png"));
```

Now the problem is that I did fix it by entering:

```
setCardBack = new ImageView(new Image("image/cardDown.png"));
```

the problem is that when doing so I threw another NullPointerException when it tried to access that image in the loadCard method here is the part that threw the exception:

```
cardBack[0].setVisible(true);
```

Here is the full class (Btw the below code wasn't changed to reflect the above change I claimed I made so that you all can see the original unedited coded):

```
public class PlayerTableCardPane extends Pane {
// Data Fields
ImageView[] cardBack;
private int cardXOffset;
private int cardHeight;
private int cardCount;

// StackPane for cards
StackPane cardStack;

/** Constructor */
public PlayerTableCardPane() {
    this.cardStack = new StackPane();
    this.cardBack = new ImageView[5];
    this.cardHeight = 50;
    this.cardXOffset = 5;
    this.cardCount = 0;

    ImageView tempCard = null;
    for (ImageView setCardBack: cardBack) {
        setCardBack.setImage(new Image("image/cardDown.png"));
        setCardBack.setVisible(false);
        setCardBack.setFitHeight(cardHeight);
        setCardBack.setPreserveRatio(true);

        if (tempCard != null) {
            setCardBack.setX(tempCard.getX() + cardXOffset);
        }

        tempCard = setCardBack;
    }

    getChildren().add(this.cardStack);
}

/** Constructor for setting custom height */
public PlayerTableCardPane(int cardHeight, int cardXOffset) {
    this.cardStack = new StackPane();
    this.cardBack = new ImageView[5];
    this.cardXOffset = cardXOffset;
    this.cardHeight = cardHeight;
    this.cardCount = 0;

    ImageView tempCard = null;
    for (ImageView setCardBack: cardBack) {
        setCardBack = new ImageView(new Image("image/cardDown.png"));
        setCardBack.setVisible(false);
        setCardBack.setFitHeight(cardHeight);
        setCardBack.setPreserveRatio(true);

        if (tempCard != null) {
            setCardBack.setX(tempCard.getX() + cardXOffset);
        }

        tempCard = setCardBack;
    }

    getChildren().add(this.cardStack);
}

/** Get cardXOffset */
public int getCardXOffset() {
    return this.cardXOffset;
}

/** Set cardXOffset */
public void setCardXOffset(int cardXOffset) {
    this.cardXOffset = cardXOffset;
}

/** Get cardCount */
public int getCardCount() {
    return this.cardCount;
}

/** Set cardCount */
public void setCardCount(int cardCount) {
    this.cardCount = cardCount;
}

/** Load cards into StackPane */
public void loadCard() {
    if (cardCount == 0) {
        cardBack[0].setVisible(true);
    } else if (cardCount == 1) {
        cardBack[1].setVisible(true);
    } else if (cardCount == 2) {
        cardBack[2].setVisible(true);
    } else if (cardCount == 3) {
        cardBack[3].setVisible(true);
    } else if (cardCount == 4) {
        cardBack[4].setVisible(true);
    }
    this.cardCount++;
}

/** Hide last card() */
public void hideLastCard() {
    if (cardCount == 4) {
        cardBack[4].setVisible(false);
    } else if (cardCount == 3) {
        cardBack[3].setVisible(false);
    } else if (cardCount == 2) {
        cardBack[2].setVisible(false);
    } else if (cardCount == 1) {
        cardBack[1].setVisible(false);
    } else if (cardCount == 0) {
        cardBack[0].setVisible(false);
    }
    this.cardCount--;
}

/** Replace card with FaceUp Image */
public void setCardImg(ImageView card, int cardPos) {
    cardBack[cardPos].setImage(card.getImage());
}
```

}

and here is the last exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at Casino_Poker.PlayerTableCardPane.loadCard(PlayerTableCardPane.java:94)
at Casino_Poker.Main.dealCards(Main.java:444)
at Casino_Poker.Main.lambda$signIn$1(Main.java:249)
at Casino_Poker.Main$$Lambda$4/86482238.handle(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:204)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8175)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:204)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3746)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1800(Scene.java:3471)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1695)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2486)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:314)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:243)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:345)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:526)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:898)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(WinApplication.java:39)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(WinApplication.java:112)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: So far I have a total of 1633 lines of code in this program, it's my first real project since I started programming. I'm starting to get better but I obviously still need a bit of work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Null Pointer Exception you get is because although you've declared

```
 this.cardBack = new ImageView[5];
```

, the array is empty, without any actual `ImageView` objects in the indexes. You need to instantiate `ImageView` objects in the array to actually be able to do anything with them. You "fixed" your first error by instantiating an `ImageView` on which you executed the rest of the methods in the loop's body.

The reason why you're still getting a Null Pointer Exception is because of your enhanced for loop, which makes `setCardBack` a local variable. Modifications to existing objects are allowed, but you can't create new objects in your array. Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14137219/java-enhanced-for-loop-editing-original-array-values) for more info.

You can use a regular for loop instead to instantiate your `ImageView`s.

```
cardBack = new ImageView[5];
for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
    cardBack[i] = new ImageView(new Image("image/cardDown.png"));
```

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate that, I didn't quite understand the ForEach loop. Now that you explained it, I understand it a lot better.

Answer (score 1):

The following code should fix your error and the comments should hopefully explain the reasons for the error.

### Default Constructor :

```
/** Constructor */
public PlayerTableCardPane() {
    // Calling an overloaded constructor is a lot less
    // work than writing out two constructors with minor
    // differences.
    this(50, 5);
}
```

### Overloaded Constructor :

```
/** Constructor for setting custom height and X offset */
public PlayerTableCardPane(int height, int xOffset) {
    this.cardStack = new StackPane();
    this.cardBack = new ImageView[5];
    this.cardHeight = height;
    this.cardXOffset = xOffset;
    this.cardCount = 0;
    
    // There is no need to define the ImageView object
    // outside of the for loop unless you need to use
    // the ImageView object after the for loop.
    // ImageView tempCard = null;
    
    // I don't like using for-each unless I have to.
    for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
        
        Image newImage = new Image("image/cardDown.png");
        
        // The NullPointerException came from trying to
        // access the property of an uninstantiated
        // ImageViewer in the cardBack array.
        ImageView setCardBack = new ImageView();
        setCardBack.setImage(newImage);
        
        setCardBack.setVisible(false);
        setCardBack.setFitHeight(cardHeight);
        setCardBack.setPreserveRatio(true);
        
        // this next line does what your conditional does without
        // the need for any conditional, also it avoids testing for
        // null, and removes the need for a tempCard variable.
        setCardBack.setX(index * cardXOffset);
        
        /*
        if (tempCard != null) {
            setCardBack.setX(tempCard.getX() + cardXOffset);
        }
        */
        
        // There is no longer a need for the next line.
        // tempCard = setCardBack;
        
        // Add the dynamically created and instantiated ImageView
        // object to this.cardBack.
        this.cardBack[index] = setCardBack;
    }
    
    // You have to add the array of ImageViews to the StackPanel,
    // before adding the StackPanel to the Panel that this class
    // etends.
    this.cardStack.getChildren().add(this.cardBack);
    this.getChildren().add(this.cardStack);
    
}
```

Let me know if you need further help or if this code leads to more errors, I'm happy to help.

Comment: Yeah, this definitely puts things into perspective and i like how you cleaned up the code while eliminating the tempCard variable.

Answer (score 0):

And I forgot about the overload feature, that's going to make my code look a lot nicer

Comment: Didn't mean to post this as an answer, still getting used to this android app :/