# How to replace a string in jsp

Tags: java, string, replace

I have a string url like `http://google.com`. I need to remove `'http://'` from the URL. I have tried the method `.replace("http://","")`, but it is not working.

```
Web web = org.getWeb();
webUrl = web.getUrl();
out.println("webUrl :"+webUrl );  // here it prints:: http://google.com
webUrl.replace("http://","");
out.println("webUrl :"+webUrl );  // here also it prints:: http://google.com
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
webUrl = webUrl.replace("http://","");
```

As [replace returns the replaced string](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29)

Answer (score 4):

You need to do like following.String is immutable class.replace will return you new String object.

```
webUrl = webUrl.replace("http://","");
```

Refer [String is immutable. What exactly is the meaning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798403/string-is-immutable-what-exactly-is-the-meaning)