# Final static can be changed?

Tags: java

I wrote my code but now i am trying to change to see what is happening.

In the object class field,

```
static final String msg="here";
```

And in the same object, in a methot

```
public void givemessage(int no)
{
    System.out.println("look.");       
    System.out.println(msg);
}
```

here it gives "here" when i call from main. But

```
public void names(String[] names)
{
    String msg=" - ";
    System.out.println(msg);
}
```

Here when i call from main it gives -, not "here" BUt it was final static. Why did it change and why is there no compile error? Or i misunderstood all java?

Comment: The local variable in your `names` method hides the static variable.

Comment: Oh ok thank you all. I could not learn this with reading.

Answer (score 8):

You are using two different variables, the class variable is immutable (final) but the local one is not, they have the same name but they are not the same.

If you want to verify this, put in your main method something like **MyClassName.msg="-"** and you'll see the compiler will complain.

Comment: immutable != final. They are two different concepts. In fact, the String class is an immutable class. Please read here for further explanation http://stackoverflow.com/a/8798424/2542027

Answer (score 4):

This is called shadowing... the String which is passed to `System.out.println` is the one you defined within your names method as it has a tighter scope as the one on class level.
Check this out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing

Comment: i wouldn't agree with the term shadowing, since you can still access both variables

Answer (score 2):

`msg` is a local variable in the `names` method. It doesnt change the variable at class level.

Answer (score 1):

it did not change.

in this snippet, your accessing the local variable.

```
public void names(String[] names)
{
    String msg=" - ";
    System.out.println(msg);
}
```

if you want to access the static field:

```
System.out.println(ClassName.msg);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are defining a local variable named `msg` inside the `names()` method . It is not the same as the `static final` class method. The local variable inside the method hides the class variable.

Answer (score 1):

It did not change. You've "hidden" your `static final` member behind the local variable. The `static final` variable still has the old value - you can access it using `XXX.msg`, where `XXX` is the name of your class.

Answer (score 1):

`String msg=" - ";` is a local variable stored in stack whereas `static final String msg="here";` is a class level variable stored in permgen space till java 6(stored in heap in java7). In nutshell you are referring two different variables here