# String Insertion won't take any effect

Tags: c#, string

Inserting a string into a string doesn't appear to have any effect. I'm using the following code:

```
string stNum = string.Format("{0:00}", iValue);
DesiredCode.Insert(0, stNum);
txtCode.Text = DesiredCode;
```

Breakpoints show `stNum` has the desired value, and DesiredCode is also as we would expect before insertion.
But after insertion, nothing will happen and the DesiredCode is the same as before!

Can someone please point me in the right direction as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks everyone, there was a silly mistake and I thought it is similar to some static extensions but I should return it back to itself.

Comment: I've put some +1s to people answering and got some -1s :D, anyway all the answers seems correct and the same, I got the answer instantly, Jon was more explanatory.

Comment: It's probably because of how you wrote your question; I had to read some parts twice before I understood what you were trying to say.

Comment: I agree with you, I was shocked for getting a strange result as it seemed to me, and also I think I had some grammatical errors in my text. thanks  for reforming it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strings are immutable. *All* the methods like `Replace` and `Insert` return a *new* string which is the result of the operation, rather than changing the data in the *existing* string. So you probably want:

```
txtCode.Text = DesiredCode.Insert(0, stNum);
```

Or for the whole block, using direct `ToString` formatting instead of using `string.Format`:

```
txtCode.Text = DesiredCode.Insert(0, iValue.ToString("00"));
```

Or even clearer, in my opinion, would be to use string concatenation:

```
txtCode.Text = iValue.ToString("00") + DesiredCode;
```

Note that *none* of these will change the value of `DesiredCode`. If you want to do that, you'd need to assign back to it, e.g.

```
DesiredCode = iValue.ToString("00") + DesiredCode;
txtCode.Text = DesiredCode;
```

Comment: Would it aid clarity to state that the methods Replace, Insert, etc. are *functions*?

Comment: Thanks Jon, the SO doesn't allow me to accept until some minutes.

Answer (score 3):

Strings are [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object)!

```
DesiredCode = DesiredCode.Insert(0, stNum);
```

Answer (score 2):

[Strings are immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798403/string-is-immutable-what-exactly-is-the-meaning) in C#. What this means is that you need to assign the return value of [`String.Insert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert.aspx) to a `string` variable after the operation in order to access it.

```
string stNum = string.Format("{0:00}", iValue);
DesiredCode = DesiredCode.Insert(0, stNum);
txtCode.Text = DesiredCode;
```