# Modifying items in a List(of String) works/fails with certain approaches

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I am trying to do a search/replace on values within a List(of String).

```
Dim l As New List(Of String) From {"Hello", Chr(10), "World"}
```

Iterate the list, and perform the search and replace:

```
For Each s As String In l
    s = s.Replace(Chr(10), String.Empty)
Next
```

However, tracing this back out, the `Chr(10)` has not been replaced.  `Chr(10)` is a line break. Tracing with:

```
Trace.Warn(String.Join(",", l))
```

outputs

```
Hello,
,World
```

Attempting this *slightly* differently works perfectly however:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To l.Count - 1
    l(i) = l(i).Replace(Chr(10), String.Empty)
Next
```

Output:

```
Hello,,World
```

I thought that `s` within the `For` loop provided an instance to the actual string, not a copy of it?  Can anyone clarify what's going on here?

Comment: String objects are **immutable** as they were value types. It doesn't matter where you store them...you can create a new modified one but you can't change an existing one in-place

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti thank you very much.  I went to do some research and found this very helpful explanation of strings and immutability http://stackoverflow.com/a/17942294/792888 (tagged as Java but that doesn't matter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first snippet:

```
For Each s As String In l
   s = s.Replace(Chr(10), String.Empty)
Next
```

`s` is a local reference to the string in the list.  You are re-assigning the *reference* to a different string, but the list still has the original reference, pointing to the original string.

Your second loop is replacing the reference *in the list* with a reference to the new string, therefore you get your expected result.

Comment: Because you're assigning new value to a local variable (bad habit to change foreach, anyway) but you're not updating your list.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Did you actually read the answer?  That's exactly what I'm explaining

Answer (score 1):

Adriano Repetti is right.
but depend on your further collection usage the follwing might be a use-case

```
Dim l = New List(Of String)() From { _
    "Hello", _
    Chr(10), _
    "World" _
}
Trace.Warn([String].Join(",", l.Select(Function(s) s.Replace(Chr(10), String.Empty))))
```