# String.equals with for each and for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach

```
String[] rgb = new String[3];

rgb[0] = Integer.toHexString(color.getRed());
rgb[1] = Integer.toHexString(color.getGreen());
rgb[2] = Integer.toHexString(color.getBlue());

for(String el : rgb)
{
    if(el.equals("0"))
    {
        el = "00";
    }
}

for(int i = 0; i<3; i++)
{
    if(rgb[i].equals("0"))
    {
        rgb[i] = "00";
    }
}
```

In the above code I evaluate each index based on weather or not each is = to zero. 
yet it always runs false in the foreach loop and true when appropriate in the for loop. 
can someone explain what  is happening behind the scenes to make this happen?

**i am not  running them sequentially they are both there for demo purposes.**

Comment: It doesn't 'run false' in the foreach loop - when you ask questions, make sure you check the assertions you're making, often doing that will let you answer the question yourself.

Comment: @Shahzeb color is a variable that holds the type java.awt.Color

Comment: @pvg right, its always good to take a step back and question your assumptions, thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your `for-each` loop, the String `el` is not actually a reference to the array `rgb`. It just holds the value of a given index in the array. Therefore, in this case, you have to use a normal `for` loop to modify the contents of the array; otherwise the contents of `el` are just overwritten each iteration of the loop.

A visual explanation:

```
String[] i = new String[]{"Hi", "Hello"};     <------- Contains two indexes.
for(String str : i){
    str = str + "!";
}
```

First iteration:

- `str` is set to `i[0]`, which has a value of `"Hi"`
- `str` is set to `str + "!"`, changing `str` to `"Hi!"`
- end of braces; `str` is discarded

Second iteration:

- `str` is set to `i[1]`, which has a value of `"Hello"`
- `str` is set to `str + "!"`, changing `str` to `"Hello!"`
- `for` loop ends; `str` is discarded

In no case are the values of `i` ever changed, because the values of `str` are separate references to Strings.

See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798403/string-is-immutable-what-exactly-is-the-meaning) about the concept of **immutability**([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object)).