# Change value of a string in another activity (java/android)

Tags: java, string, android-activity

if I have a string in activityA, how can  I modify this string in another activity (for example activityB)???

Note: I don't want to passing data from one activity to another, so I don't won't the copy of the string, but the real string of activityA in activity B

Comment: Strings are immutable so this is not possible

Comment: No, @andrewdleach is correct, strings are immutable. But I don't think that is what your question was about. If you want to read about it, go here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798403/string-is-immutable-what-exactly-is-the-meaning

Comment: Oh ok thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to make the variable global. For example (these classes are in two separate files):

```
public class A {
    public static String s = "A";
    //...
}

public class B {
    //...

   public static void vandalizeClassA() {
       System.out.println(A.s); //output will be "A"
       A.s = "B was here"; 
       System.out.println(A.s); //output will be "B was here"
   }
}
```

This is not specific to Android activities.

Comment: So I should declare the string public and static and then I call with nameClass.nameVariable my string in another activity?

Comment: Yes, that is one way to do it.

Comment: After the second System.out.print, the value of the string in class A is "B was here"??

Comment: Well, after the `A.s = "B was here"` it is changed to that. I'm just printing it out to show you.