# Regex matches but doesn't work on Java

Tags: java, regex

I'm using this regex to match and replace a part of a string:

```
(.*)<a href=\\"(.*)\\" class=\\"PopupItemLink\\">(.*)<\\\/a>(.*)
```

This string is an example: (https://regexr.com/3n1f1)

```
\n&7This is the alert body\n\nYour name: HAlexTM\nYour ID: 1\nHere the link: <a href=\"test.com\" class=\"PopupItemLink\">Hey<\/a>\n\nThis is a html test: <p>Hey<\/p>\n&8Thu Jun 09 18:07:30 CEST 2016
```

This part of the string (matched by the RegEX) should be replaced with `Hey`

```
<a href=\"test.com\" class=\"PopupItemLink\">Hey<\/a>
```

So in Java I use this code

```java
if (asit.matches("(.*)<a href=\\\\\"(.*)\\\\\" class=\\\\\"PopupItemLink\\\\\">(.*)<\\\\\\/a>(.*)")) {
    asit.replaceAll("<a href=\\\\\"(.*)\\\\\" class=\\\\\"PopupItemLink\\\\\"", "$1");
    asit.replaceAll(">(.*)<\\\\\\/a>", "$1");
    return asit;
}
```

But it doesn't return anything, what's the problem?

Comment: Java strings are **immutable**. `asit=asit.replaceAll()`

Comment: @PM77-1 Sorry, what does this mean?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798403/string-is-immutable-what-exactly-is-the-meaning

Comment: @PM77-1 Ok..the replacement thing is clarified, but anyway it still doesn't match the Regex (the if will bypass)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved it removing the if block and write just replaceAll(), reassigning the variable value since Strings are immutable (thanks to @PM77-1)

```
output = output.replaceAll("<a href=\"(.*)\" class=\"PopupItemLink\"", "$1");
output = output.replaceAll(">(.*)<\\/a>", " ($1)");
return output;
```