# Total number of String object created in below code?

Tags: java, string

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = new String("abc");
        String b = "abc";
        String c = "abc" + "KDF" + "gh" +"rt" +"jk";

    }
```

Please find below byte code of the code.

```
Compiled from "NumOfStringObject.java"
public class com.practise.general.NumOfStringObject extends java.lang.Object{
public com.practise.general.NumOfStringObject();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   return

public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0:   new     #2; //class java/lang/String
   3:   dup
   4:   ldc     #3; //String abc
   6:   invokespecial   #4; //Method java/lang/String."<init>":(Ljava/lang/Strin
g;)V
   9:   astore_1
   10:  ldc     #3; //String abc
   12:  astore_2
   13:  ldc     #5; //String abcKDFghrtjk
   15:  astore_3
   16:  return

}
```

I have no experience in reading/understanding byte code, i guess total of 3 String objects are getting created.

let me know your thoughts.

Comment: yep there a 3 Strings you create

Comment: Okay, thanks, but why intermediate objects like "KDF", "gh" , "rt", "jk" are not getting stored in String Pool.?

Comment: @Lovesh I gave you the link to the specification, where this behavior is defined

Comment: You've answered your own question. You should really ask _why_ this behaviour happens rather than asking nothing at all.

Comment: Okay, thanks @xenteros i will follow the link

Answer (score 4):

Yes, three. At first glance, you'd think more, but the *compiler* will combine string constants; [details in JLS§15.28 - *Constant Expressions*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28). So the compiler effectively treats the body of your `main` as:

```
String a = new String("abc");
String b = "abc";
String c = "abcKDFghrtjk";
```

It also reuses the same string for equivalent constants in the class (which are [interned](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern--), so the same string can be used across classes as well), which means there's only one `"abc"` created by the two occurrences of the `"abc"` literal in that code.

So:

- One `"abc"` from the constant (literal)
- One `"abcKDFghrtjk"` from the other constant (result of combining several literals)
- One `"abc"` you created explicitly as a separate object in the first line of code via `new String`

Comment: Hi Sir TJ, Im wondering if only `String literals` are only treated constants in compilation?

Comment: @msagala: Anything that's a constant value per the specification; [details here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28). So that's literals, and also references to [`final` string variables and fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4) (which the spec sometimes calls member variables).

Answer (score 2):

1. literal `"abc"` is created.
2. String having same characters as `"abc"` is created.
3. literal `"abcKDFghrtjk"` is created.

[Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5):

```
"This is a string"    // a string containing 16 characters
"This is a " +        // actually a string-valued constant expression,
    "two-line string"    // formed from two string literals
```

> Strings computed by concatenation at run time are newly created and therefore distinct.
>   Strings computed by constant expressions ([§15.28](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)) are computed at compile time and then treated as if they were literals.

Answer (score -4):

String is **immutable**

Read the discussion here. Should help you.
[String is immutable. What exactly is the meaning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798403/string-is-immutable-what-exactly-is-the-meaning)

In brief. **If you ever witness your String variable changing its value in your code, you can safely assume that a new object is created**.

```
String s = new String("some value");
```

and

```
String s = "some value";
```

are very same. When you use `=` the value is not set but a new object is actually created under the same reference `s`

EDIT:
For the "Downvoters", the answer is **YES**. **Three objects are created**

Comment: How does this relate to the question of how many strings are created in the given code? Besides, `"some value"` was already created in the string pool in the first statement, and `s` is merely assigned an existing reference. Nothing to do with immutability.

Comment: The number of strings created is not related to the fact that they are immutable. And the statement "When you use `=` the value is not set but a new object is actually created" is wrong when the value is a literal that has already been used in the program.

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson thats why I put a line "Whenever u see the string changing value. a new object is created". Not sure why is this answer went completely misleading