# Why String addition using + allows moved to new address in java?

Tags: java, string

I have got some information that string addition using + allows moved to new memory address in java but  in case for int  it is not happening why?

means

```
String a="fi-rstname";
a=a+" "+lastname;
```

a+" "+lastname moves to the new address instead of address of a

but for

```
 int a=22;
a=a+2323;
```

a+2323; vale does not move to the new address for addition why?

Comment: Strings are immutable in Java

Comment: `int`s are primitives. Their values are not stored at _memory address_ (aka heap).

Comment: Also, [Immutability of Strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552301/immutability-of-strings-in-java)

Comment: It's not string "addition", it's string concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String is immutable in Java. You can't change the content of immutable field after initialization. That is the reason, you create a new memory case.

You can get more information in this post : [String is immutable. What exactly is the meaning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798403/string-is-immutable-what-exactly-is-the-meaning) that explain well why String is immutable.

Answer (score 0):

**Because String is immutable so each time you make change in string it'll create new object**

in int we can make changes because primitive datatype is mutable(changeable).