# How to remove Miscellaneous Symbols Block from the Unicode String

Tags: java, string, unicode, char, emoji

I want to `remove miscellaneous symbols block from Unicode string` using regular expression may also try but none of them regular expression I think current can anyone help me for this issue how I can remove miscellaneous symbols block from the string.

**Unicode String**

```
\u263A\uD83D\uDE0A\uD83D\uDE22)\uD83C\uDF82
```

**Code:**

```
String input = "\u263A\uD83D\uDE0A\uD83D\uDE22)\uD83C\uDF82";
input.replaceAll("[\u2600-\u26FF]|[\u2700-\u27BF]", "");
```

**Expected:**

```
\uD83D\uDE0A\uD83D\uDE22)\uD83C\uDF82
```

but it will be not working how I can solve this issue.

Comment: Tip: You can match Unicode blocks with `\p{InMiscellaneousSymbols}|\p{InDingbats}` or `[\p{InMiscellaneousSymbols}\p{InDingbats}]`. This is much more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Input text contains u-escaped characters, as text consisting out of a backslash, 'u' and 4 hexadecimal Digits, convert them first to real `char`s.

```
input = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(Input); // From Apache commons
input = input.replaceAll("[\u2600-\u26FF]|[\u2700-\u27BF]", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

It not work because [String is immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798403/string-is-immutable-what-exactly-is-the-meaning) in Java you have to use assign the result to the input like this :

```
String result = input.replaceAll("[\u2600-\u26FF]|[\u2700-\u27BF]", "");
```

Or simply :

```
input = input.replaceAll("[\u2600-\u26FF]|[\u2700-\u27BF]", "");
```

So if you make a print like this :

```
System.out.println(input);
System.out.println("\uD83D\uDE0A\uD83D\uDE22)\uD83C\uDF82");
```

Both gives :

```
)
)
```

Comment: thank you YCF_L can you try please this one
String input = "\\u263A\\uD83D\\uDE0A\\uD83D\\uDE22\\uD83C\\uDF82";
input = input.replaceAll("[\\u2600-\\u26FF]|[\\u2700-\\u27BF]", "");
System.out.println(input);
Output:

Comment: \u263A\uD83D\uDE0A\uD83D\uDE22\uD83C\uDF82

Comment: @KishanDonga the output is correct because you are using double back-slash instead you have to use only one with Unicode String like `String input = "\u263A\uD83D\uDE0A\uD83D\uDE22\uD83C\uDF82"; 
input = input.replaceAll("[\u2600-\u26FF]|[\u2700-\u27BF]", ""); 
System.out.println(input);` the output now is 