# How do I append characters in Java?

Tags: java, string, char, append

In this program, I want to not only print the results but to save the results as a string. How do I do that?
Also, how do I 'return' a string value that can be printed?
(This program is removes all the vowels in the 'ad' string except the first letter of the word)

```
public class RemoveVowels {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "";
        remove("Remove all vowels from string except the first letters");
        System.out.println();

    }

    static String remove(String a) {

        char c = '\0';
        String ss = "";
        String s = ("" + a.charAt(0));
        String sent = ("" + s);
        boolean vowel = false;
        boolean first = false;

        System.out.print(s);

        for (int i = 1; i <= (a.length() - 1); i++) {

            c = a.charAt(i);

            if (a.charAt(i - 1) == ' ')
                first = true;
            else
                first = false;

            if (((c == 'a' || c == 'e') || (c == 'i' || c == 'o')) || (c == 'u' || c == 'y'))
                vowel = true;
            else
                vowel = false;

            if ((first == true) || (vowel == false)) {
                s = ("" + c);
                System.out.print(s);

            }

        }
        return s;
    }

}
```

Comment: which result you want to print?

Comment: I'm already printing it out with System.out.print(s) - but I want to be able to save that string that prints out (since it prints out one character at a time as it's looping)
I also want to know how do I return the value of that entire printed string, so that I can print it in the main method.

Comment: change s = ("" + c); to  s+=("" + c);  but i suggest you use StringBuilder

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to append is just using `+` as in `s = s + c`. This isn't the best way to do it performance wise since a new String is created every time (due to Strings being immutable). Instead you may use a `StringBuilder` e.g.

```
//Create outside of loop
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
//Append in loop
sb.append(c);
//Print when done
System.out.println(sb);
//Return the String to the caller
return sb.toString();
```

Comment: I like the s=s+c option. How do I use that in my code and then print out the result of the saved string?

Comment: As I said, the StringBuilder way is better, but if you REALLY wanna use s = s + c you may simply change s = ("" + c); into s = s + c;. The result is stored in s and you may print it and return it just as you do now.

Answer (score 0):

change `s = ("" + c);` to `s+=("" + c);` but i suggest you use `StringBuilder`

Answer (score 0):

First thing : you add many things not required : parenthesis, empty String as you concatenate, explicit `== false`,  `== true`, etc..
It makes unecessary verbosity.

Then about your question, that :

```
 s = ("" + c);
```

could be replaced by :

```
 s+ = c;
```

It doesn't overwrite any longer `s` but it concatenates the `c` value to the previous value stored in `s`.

You can also use a `StringBuilder` :

```
    StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 1; i <= (ad.length() - 1); i++) {
         ...
        c = ad.charAt(i);

        if (first  || !vowel) {
            content.append(c);
            System.out.print(content.toString());
        }
         ...
    }
```

Note that no one of these solutions are really better.
`StringBuilder` is theorically more efficient at runtime from a some number of concatenation but `String` concatenations in source code may be optimized both at compilation time and at runtime.
So just use the way that makes your code more readable.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to take a look at [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).
Append the string that you're printing inside `System.out.print(s);` i.e. the string `s` to the StringBuilder object.

Return the String generated from StringBuilder object.
The following code illustrates this.

```
    String modify(String ad) {
        StringBuilder resultBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        // part before loop goes here.        
        for(int i = 1; i <= (ad.length() - 1); i++) {
            // inside loop computation
            System.out.print(s);  // optional
            resultBuilder.append(s);
        }
        return resultBuilder.toString();
    }
```

You can use the returned string the way you want.

Note: An easy way would be to keep appending results to String `s` but that is not the best way because Strings are [immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798403/string-is-immutable-what-exactly-is-the-meaning) and will cause a new string to be generated every time. I would recommend using the StringBuilder.