# java strings inmutable but the code doesn't shows that

Tags: java, string, immutability

I was learning string concepts, so wrote a code,expected a different output but got something very unexpected.

```
class stringmute
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String s1="Hello "; //string one.
        System.out.println("Str1:"+s1);
        String s2= s1+"world"; //New String.
        System.out.println("Str2="+s2);
        s1=s1+"World!!"; //This should produce only Hello right?
        System.out.println("Str1 modified:"+s1);

    }
}
```

when I execute the above code i get the output as:

```
Str1:Hello 
Str2=Hello world
Str1 modified:Hello World!!
```

if i've done something wrong please let me know.
Since strings are immutable, which implies we should get the output of the "Str1 Modified" as "HELLO" instead of "HELLO WORLD!!".

Comment: This should be a good read to understand immutability. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798403/string-is-immutable-what-exactly-is-the-meaning

Comment: String objects are immutable.  References to Strings are not (necessarily).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you assign s1 as :

```
s1=s1+"World!!";
```

New String created in jvm string pool and assigned to s1.

So it's value became "Hello World!!"