# How can I set a default String format in my constructor in Java?

Tags: java, string, constructor, format

I have got a constructor in Java that uses a string. This string is always going to be a number.

```
private final String number;

public Number (String s) {
    this.number = s;
}
```

Since this string is always a number in my case I would like this string always to use a certain format. 
For example, when creating some new Numbers in my main method:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

    Number one = new Number("1");
    Number ten = new Number("10");

    System.out.println("Number one is: " + one);
    System.out.println("Number ten is: " + ten);
}
```

I would like it to print out something like this:

```
Number one is: 000001
Number ten is: 000010
```

How can I declare such a format in my constructor (in my case it has to be in the constructor)?

EDIT: Again, I know that there are better implementations such as just avoiding to use a string but there are reasons why I use a string (don't ask me why).

Comment: Why must it be in the constructor?  Could be static final.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I finally have found the answer in this post:
[Left padding a String with Zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469717/left-padding-a-string-with-zeros)

In my case that would mean for the constructor:

```
public Number(String s) {
    this.number = String.format("%06d", Integer.parseInt(s));
}
```

Maybe this is helpful for anyone in the future.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use String and I wouldn't call it `Number` which is a common builtin type. You might even what your "number" class to extend Number

```
class MyNumber extends Number {
     final long num;

     MyNumber(long num) { this.num = num; }

     public String toString() { return String.format("%06d", num); }

     // other number methods.
}
```

You should consider using a `static factory` for creating your numbers just the way Integer and BigDecimal and others do.

Answer (score 1):

" This string is always going to be a number. "

Something about this sentence seems wrong to me. If you're internally representing a number, you should use a numeric type. Depending on what fits your needs, it could be a `double`, an `int` or a decimal type such as `BigDecimal`.

When you need to print that number somewhere (and only then), you should convert it to a `String`. Java supplies a rich set of methods to format numbers under `java.text.NumberFormat`.

Answer (score 0):

you can just override the tostring method in the class

```
   public String toString() { 
   }
```

unless there is some other reason to format the number

Answer (score 0):

First, in your constructor, you might add a parsing step to check the validity of the String (defensive programming, throwing an IllegalArgumentException or an ad-hoc Exception subclass).

Then, for padding a number with 0 : [How can I pad an integers with zeros on the left?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473282/left-padding-integers-with-zeros-in-java)