# appending zeros to make number of 10 digit

Tags: java

I know it is a simple question and I know the way to do it, only need of mine here is Performance and with less time as possible it should do.

I am getting input as

```
long l = 149;
```

I want to make this number of size 10 with additional numbers to be added at starting to make it of 10 digit.
above number should get converted to,

```
   0000000149.
```

Similarly,

```
1      -> 0000000001
13     -> 0000000013
888888 -> 0000888888
```

1.
I tried with loop, like checking number length, subtracting number length by 10, then adding number of zero as the subtraction result i got.

2 Already created array like

```
arr[0, 00, 000, 0000, 00000, 000000, 0000000, 00000000, 000000000, 0000000000];
```

here I am doing same thing, subtracting my number length with 10 and getting arr[numberLenth -10] + number

I am getting desired result.

I want to make sure to check is there any better solution to this like using bitwise operator for such requirement?

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473282/left-padding-integers-with-zeros-in-java

Comment: Or may be this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469717/left-padding-a-string-with-zeros

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/391978/44853

Comment: in which way are you creating these formatting? If console, you can always just do System.out.format("%10d", numberVariable);

Comment: Thanks... i got answer on link pointed by @Tichodroma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you like this?

```
String.format("%010d", 123);
```

Comment: `"%10d"` prints leading zeroes? Since when?

Comment: I got the answer, i need to do like String data = String.format("%010d", 1234);