# show 0 as prefix if value is less than 9

Tags: java, android

Still i am getting file name like below:

**B-13-4-006.jpg**

and

**B-5-7-008.jpg**

but now i want to show 0 as prefix if value less than < 9 else as it is, in short want to show values in double figures, see my code below using to file name

```
               "B-" + // prefix
                LoginActivity.strEventID + "-" + // eventID 
                LoginActivity.strOperativeID + "-" + // operativeID 
                getNextNumber() + // counter 
                ".jpg"
```

but **i require**, files name should look like below:

**B-13-04-006.jpg**

and

**B-05-07-008.jpg**

Comment: That's an overkill. Why don't you use the string padding? See [http://stackoverflow.com/a/4469748/2649012](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4469748/2649012)

Comment: Use `String.valueOf(value)` instead of `Integer.toString(value)`

Comment: 'less than 9' needs to be changed into 'less than 10'...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you seem to have *strings* that need to be (optionally) padded with zeros, you can use a *different* approach than generally used to pad *integers*:

```
public String addPadding(int length, String text) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    // First, add (length - 'length of text') number of '0'
    for (int i = length - text.length(); i > 0; i--) {
        sb.append('0');
    }

    // Next, add string itself
    sb.append(text);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

so you can use:

```
"B-" + // prefix
    addPadding(2, LoginActivity.strEventID) + "-" + // eventID 
    addPadding(2, LoginActivity.strOperativeID) + "-" + // operativeID 
    getNextNumber() + // counter 
    ".jpg"
```

There are lots of other possibilities to pad a String, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469717/left-padding-a-string-with-zeros) for more details/possibilities.

Answer (score 14):

Use `String.format("%02d", yournumber);` to show 0 with a number if less than 10 (for two digits number).

*Use method like*

```
private String getPaddedNumber(int number) {
    return String.format("%02d", number);
}
```

---

You can read [Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) documents for more details.

---

***How to use into your code***

```
"B-" + // prefix
        getPaddedNumber(LoginActivity.strEventID) + "-" + // eventID 
        getPaddedNumber(LoginActivity.strOperativeID) + "-" + // operativeID 
        getPaddedNumber(getNextNumber()) + // counter 
        ".jpg"
```

Comment: pankaj not getting how to use this in my existing code

Comment: Pass your IDs to his method, that's how.

Comment: getting same issue, like when i tried your code my self into my code: The method getPaddedNumber(int) in the type CameraLauncherActivity is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: What is the type of `LoginActivity.strEventID` and other 2 variables? Are they string

Comment: If they then you can parse them into integer.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String convert(int n){
    return n < 10 ? "0" + n : "" + n;
}
```

Comment: Pankaj Kumar's approach is better though.

Answer (score 0):

http://openbook.galileocomputing.de/javainsel/javainsel_04_011.html#dodtp6223d54a-d5d8-4ea7-a487-03f519d21c6b

Just use a formatter. I think this is the easiest and most accurate approach