# How to add 0 after convert from Hex to the Binary in Android?

Tags: android

I am working in **Android**.

I have convert the value from the **`Hex`** to the **`Binary`**.

For example :

```
String Hex = "02";
String Bin = Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.parseInt(Hex, 16));
Log.e(WifiP2P.TAG, "Binary is " + Bin);
```

The log show like the following:Binary is **`10`**.

**How to add the 0 after convert to the `Binary` for 8 bit ?** Like **`00000010`**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yo can check length of String, and prepend remaining 0es

Comment: try this -->String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(10)).replace(" ", "0")

Comment: Or try `String bin =new BigInteger(s, 16).toString(2);`

Comment: Try either [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4421438/1270789) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15124135/1270789).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like:

```java
//Bin is your variable containing the initial binary string 
String.format("%8s", Bin).replace(' ', '0'); //8 indicates the length of the binary string
```

It will pad `0`s to the remaining empty spaces.