# How to add leading zeros in a string of numbers to complete it to become a required 9 digit number

Tags: java, selenium

I have to automate a scenario in Selenium in which I am required to pick values from an excel file and then to input that in the login fields of the webpage. There is a check to be placed in the first value to be picked, which I am unable to complete.

Suppose I am picking up values 103030, from the first row, first column. Now this is a six digit number. The webpage field where I am supposed to enter this checks for a minimum 9 digit number.

So, if it is a six, or a seven digit number, I have to concatenate leading zeros for the remaining places.

For example,in this scenario, 103030 is a 6 digit number, and it requires three more digits to become a 9 digit number.
So I have to add three leading zeros to this- like 000103030. Similarly if it is a seven digit number- like 1030303, then I have to add 001030303.

How can this be achieved.

The way I thought it can be achieved is by finding the number of digits, subtracting that by 9 and then replacing the required number with zeroes, but I'm struggling with the logic for adding leading zeroes.

Comment: `s = "0" + s`?  That adds one leading zero.  Do that in a loop.

Comment: Can you explain it furthur

Comment: `s` is a `String`, sorry if that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use String.format (http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

Your case would use: String.format("%09d", number)

Comment: That works if `number` is an `int` or `Integer`.  If it's a `String`, it's probably not worthwhile to parse it as an integer just to be able to use `String.format`.

Answer (score 2):

Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469717/left-padding-a-string-with-zeros) for left padding a string. As mentioned in the above answer you can use `String.format(..)` or if your project depends on [Apache commons library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#leftPad(java.lang.String,%20int,%20char)) you can use `StringUtils.leftPad(....)`.

Answer (score 0):

There's not a great deal of logic involved here. If you need something elegant, try the [StringUtils#leftPad](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#leftPad%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20char%29).

This is included in the `commons-lang` apache library.