# Converting an int to a binary with a fixed number of bits

Tags: java

What is the easiest way in java to get the binary representation of an integer as a binary number with a fixed number of bits (For example, if I want to convert 3 with 5 bits, then the result would be 00011). In matlab, I can just specify the number of bits as an argument.

Comment: [Left padding a String with zeros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469717/left-padding-a-string-with-zeros) might help solve this, along with `Integer.toBinaryString(int)`.

Answer (score 12):

This is a simple way:

```
String binaryString = Integer.toBinaryString(number);
binaryString = binaryString.substring(binaryString.length() - numBits);
```

Where *number* is the integer to convert and *numBits* is the fixed number of bits you are interested in.

Comment: But... I have "String index out of range: -3" in this case...

Comment: Then you may want:  binaryString = binaryString.substring(binaryString.length() - numBits >= 0 ? binaryString.length() - numBits : 0);

Answer (score 9):

If you want to convert an `int` into its binary representation, you need to do this:

```
String binaryIntInStr = Integer.toBinaryString(int);
```

If you want to get the bit count of an `int`, you need to do this:

```
int count = Integer.bitCount(int);
```

But you couldn't **get the binary representation of an integer as a binary number with a fixed number of bits** , for example, 7 has 3 bits, but you can't set its bit count 2 or 1. Because you won't get 7 from its binary representation with 2 or 1 bit count.

Comment: The first line converts the binary integer to decimal and then parses it as binary. It if was correct it would do nothing, but it isn't correct.

Comment: @EJP I have re-edit the answer, is it right now?

Answer (score 3):

To convert n to numbOfBits of bits:

```
public static String intToBinary (int n, int numOfBits) {
   String binary = "";
   for(int i = 0; i < numOfBits; ++i, n/=2) {
      switch (n % 2) {
         case 0:
            binary = "0" + binary;
         break;
         case 1:
            binary = "1" + binary;
         break;
      }
   }

   return binary;
}
```

Comment: You forgot your **break;** statement in the code above. you'll add a 1 bit after every 0.