# How to format resource string with leading zero?

Tags: android, string

Im using strings with placeholder in my `strings.xml`

```
<string name="date">%1$d.%2$d.%3$d</string>
```

And set it in the code like:

```
String.format(context.getResources().getString(R.string.date), day, month, year);
```

If we take the 5th may for example the result now is:

```
5.5.2015
```

How can i add the leading zero for numbers smaler than ten to the string resources?

Not a duplicate of [Left padding a String with Zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469717/left-padding-a-string-with-zeros) since the solution of this question is:

```
String.format("%010d", Integer.parseInt(mystring));
```

But the format for the android resource string is:

```
%1$d
```

where the `1` indicates the index. Where should i put the `02`?

Comment: Use this kind of format "%1$tY-%1$tm-%1$td %1$tH:%1$tM:%1$tS" and use String.format("%1$tY-%1$tm-%1$td %1$tH:%1$tM:%1$tS", dateObject) to get formatted date.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use this format:

```
<string name="date">%1$02d.%2$02d.%3$d</string>
```

For further studying about format, see [Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)'s sections: *conversion*, *flags* and *width*.