# What does the dollar sign ($) do in a printf format string?

Tags: java, printf, string-formatting, system.out

I am trying to format in java using the printf statement like in this webpage: [Click Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/console_printf.htm). But I just can't figure out what the purpose of the $ sign is. Can someone please explain this to me?

Input:

```
java 100
cpp 65
python 50
```

Expected Output: ( there should be a space instead of _ )

```
 ================================
 java___________100 
 cpp___________065 
 python_________050 
 ================================
```

My code:

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("================================");
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            String s1=sc.next();
            int x=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.printf(s1 + "%03d", x);
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("================================");

    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code here, not a link. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax

Comment: In short, the dollar character is not going to solve your problem.  Try "%10.0d" instead.  Read the javadocs fof a specification of what the format string means.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is the **Argument Index**. [You can read the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html). I will try to explain the string from the tutorial for you:

```
String fmt = "%1$4s %2$10s %3$10s%n";

// format
cnsl.printft(fmt, "Items", "Quantity", "Price");
cnsl.printft(fmt, "-----", "-----", "-----");
cnsl.printft(fmt, "Tomato", "1 kg", "15");
cnsl.printft(fmt, "Potato", "5 kg", "50");
cnsl.printft(fmt, "Onion", "2 kg", "30");
cnsl.printft(fmt, "Apple", "4 kg", "80");
```

In general the format is `%[argument_index$][flags][width][.precision]conversion`.

In our example, `#$` points to the position within our `printft()` statement. We have 3 strings to be formatted and hence why our format string has `1$`, `2$`,`3$`. The number that follows its the width between each argument. This width begins at 0 which means the actual width would be +1. The `s` is our conversion to string and the `%n` new line at the end.

```
Items      Quantity      Price
-----      --------      -----
Tomato     1 kg          15
Potato     5 kg          50
Onion      2 kg          30
Apple      4 kg          80
```