# Function of Dollar Sign in Formatting Strings

Tags: java, printf

I came across a solution online on how to right-pad integers with zeros and I have a question on how exactly the printf works.

```
public static String formatString(int i, int t, String vs) {
    return String.format("%0$-"+(vs.length()-i)+"d", t).replace(" ", "0");
}
```

My question is, how does '0$-' work and how does each individual character function in that expression?

Comment: Did you read the [funny manual](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Comment: Clever solution though. Will have to keep this in mind if the need arises.

Comment: (via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33458695/what-does-the-dollar-sign-do-in-a-printf-format-string?rq=1)

Comment: My mistake on the duplicate, when I was testing searches that one I did not notice (although I might of missed it). Much appreciated.