# str_pad implemented in Java

Tags: java, string

I've seen some answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469717/left-padding-a-string-with-zeros)

But none of them add a pad to both sides of a given string.
***Example:***

```
String input = "text";
System.out.println(add_pad(input,10,"#"));
```

**Output:** `###text###`

What I am looking for is a way that add a pad to both sides of a string
and takes as arguments the string and the character or characters to fill with... Maybe something like str_pad in php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***FULL IMPLEMENTATION OF THE ORIGINAL STR_PAD***
Thanks to theINtoy user answer and I think it would be a good one (not tested yet),
but I ended up implementing the full str_pad php function in Java language, because all answers that I found has partial functionalities and I need more control over string like str_pad php does.

```
/**************************
*
* STR_PAD IMPLEMENTED
*
**************************/
public String str_pad(String input, int length, String pad, String    sense)
{
   int resto_pad = length - input.length();
   String padded = "";

   if (resto_pad <= 0){ return input; }

   if(sense.equals("STR_PAD_RIGHT"))
   {
       padded  = input;
       padded += _fill_string(pad,resto_pad);
   }
   else if(sense.equals("STR_PAD_LEFT"))
   {
       padded  = _fill_string(pad, resto_pad);
       padded += input;
   }
   else // STR_PAD_BOTH
   {
       int pad_left  = (int) Math.ceil(resto_pad/2);
       int pad_right = resto_pad - pad_left;

       padded  = _fill_string(pad, pad_left);
       padded += input;
       padded += _fill_string(pad, pad_right);
   }
   return padded;
}


protected String _fill_string(String pad, int resto )
{
   boolean first = true;
   String padded = "";

   if (resto >= pad.length())
   {
      for (int i = resto; i >= 0; i = i - pad.length())
      {
          if (i  >= pad.length())
          {
              if (first){ padded = pad; } else { padded += pad; }
          }
          else
          {
              if (first){ padded = pad.substring(0, i); } else { padded += pad.substring(0, i); }
          }
          first = false;
      }
  }
  else
  {
      padded = pad.substring(0,resto);
  }
  return padded;
}
```

USAGE - All possible test cases
============================

```
System.out.println(str_pad("coca cola 100", 10, "-", "STR_PAD_RIGHT"));
System.out.println(str_pad("coca cola", 10, "-",  "STR_PAD_RIGHT"));
System.out.println(str_pad("cocacola", 10, "-",   "STR_PAD_RIGHT"));
System.out.println(str_pad("cocacola", 10, "-",   "STR_PAD_LEFT"));
System.out.println(str_pad("cocacola", 10, "-",   "STR_PAD_BOTH"));
System.out.println(str_pad("cocacola", 15, "##",  "STR_PAD_RIGHT"));
System.out.println(str_pad("cocacola", 15, "##",  "STR_PAD_LEFT"));
System.out.println(str_pad("cocacola", 15, "##",  "STR_PAD_BOTH"));
System.out.println(str_pad("cocacola", 15, "&&&", "STR_PAD_RIGHT"));
System.out.println(str_pad("cocacola", 15, "&&&", "STR_PAD_LEFT"));
System.out.println(str_pad("cocacola", 15, "&&&", "STR_PAD_BOTH"));
System.out.println(str_pad("cocacola", 20, "***", "STR_PAD_BOTH"));
System.out.println(str_pad("cocacola", 20, "*-*", "STR_PAD_BOTH"));
System.out.println(str_pad("cocacola_light_taste_is_not_like_original", 20, ":::", "STR_PAD_BOTH"));
```

The first and last println will print all characters like do the original php str_pad function

Output:

```
System.out: coca cola 100
System.out: coca cola- 
System.out: cocacola-- 
System.out: --cocacola 
System.out: -cocacola- 
System.out: cocacola####### 
System.out: #######cocacola 
System.out: ###cocacola#### 
System.out: cocacola&&&&&&& 
System.out: &&&&&&&cocacola 
System.out: &&&cocacola&&&& 
System.out: ******cocacola****** 
System.out: *-**-*cocacola*-**-* 
System.out: cocacola_light_taste_is_not_like_original
```

If someone find any good test or improvement, You are welcome to edit this answer for a better code...

Answer (score 2):

I suspect apache commons StringUtils will come to your rescue:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#center(java.lang.String,%20int,%20char)

e.g.

```
String input = "text";
System.out.println(StringUtils.center(input,10,"#"));
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thank you, but I can not include commons.apache library in my app for some security reasons...

Answer (score 0):

There are options using `java.lang.String.format()` and `java.util.Formatter`.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html
Essentially:

These options are discussed here:

[How can I pad a String in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388461/how-can-i-pad-a-string-in-java/391978#391978)