# How to left-pad double with zeroes in Java

Tags: java, leading-zero

I need to pre-pend a number of zeroes to a double value in Java.
It is simple with integers, for example:

```
System.out.printf("%08d\n", 1);
```

Produces:
00000001

If i try the same with a real value:

```
System.out.printf("%08f\n", 1.1);
```

The produced output is 1.100000

How do i achieve 0000001.1 ?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Left padding a String with Zeros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469717/left-padding-a-string-with-zeros)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
System.out.println(String.format("%07.1f",1.1F));
```