# Padding Binary Output with 0's

Tags: java

I am trying to have a my program print out all the potential binary values based on the amount of places given.  So for instance if the given amount of places was 2, it would print `00, 01, 10, 11`.  I have figured out how to get the print out of the binary values, but the leading 0's are being deleted in the single digit values.  Is there an efficient way to fix this issue?

Below is my code:

```
import java.lang.*;

public class TestBit {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      int index = 3;
      int n = (int) Math.pow(2, index);
      for(int i=0 ; i<n ; i++){
            System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(i));
        }
   }
}
```

Below is my output:

```
0
1
10
11
100
101
110
111
```

below is my desired output:

```
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469717/left-padding-a-string-with-zeros

Comment: Use
String.format("%05d", yournumber);
Taken from:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473282/how-can-i-pad-an-integers-with-zeros-on-the-left