# How to dynamically decide how many loops I want?

Tags: java, for-loop

Here is the subject:

I have a `LinkedList list`, if the list has 3 elements, I'd like to list an entire truth table for it, for instance:

```
a b c   <---   the three elements in list
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 0
1 0 0
1 1 1
1 1 0
1 0 1
0 1 1
```

and if the list has 4 or more elements, I would like to generate a more large table.

**But I got stuck here:**

I know writing loops like this can generate the entire table:

```
       for (int a = 0; a < 2; a++){
            for (int b = 0; b < 2; b++) {
                for (int c = 0; c < 2; c++) {
                    for (int d = 0; d < 2; d++) {
                        System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + c + " " + d);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

but I can't change the number of loops based on the list size, and I think writing special cases for this is unacceptable, so is there an alternative way to do this??

Comment: Sounds like recursion might be useful.

Comment: had read some before, why asking?@ZagorulkinDmitry

Answer (score 12, accepted):

simple solution if you just want a truth table:

code:

```
int len = 3;
int num = (int)Math.pow(2, len);
for(int i=0; i<num; i++){
    // http://stackoverflow.com/a/4421438/1273830
    System.out.println(String.format("%"+len+"s", Integer.toBinaryString(i)).replace(' ', '0'));
}
```

Basic digital logic: truth tables are binary number sequences.

Comment: Thanks for the basic logic tip!

Answer (score 1):

The number of loops needs to match the number of elements.  There are two ways to solve this.

- Use recursion so that there is one loop and the method calls itself for the next level of looping.
- Use a single loop which repeats 2^n times and extracts out the components values.

Answer (score 0):

I won't write it in Java for you, but here is a pseudocode to give you an idea how to solve the problem recursively:

```
l = ['a','b','c']

def f(l, result):
    if len(l) == 0:
        print result
        return
    first = l[0]
    rest = l[1:]
    f(rest, result + [(first,0)])
    f(rest, result + [(first,1)])

f (l, [])
```

This should print something like:

```
[('a', 0), ('b', 0), ('c', 0)]
[('a', 0), ('b', 0), ('c', 1)]
[('a', 0), ('b', 1), ('c', 0)]
[('a', 0), ('b', 1), ('c', 1)]
[('a', 1), ('b', 0), ('c', 0)]
[('a', 1), ('b', 0), ('c', 1)]
[('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('c', 0)]
[('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('c', 1)]
```

Comment: So you post an _untested_ non-java solution. Why do you post this in the first place? You should post at least pseudocode which is more java like. (Slices don't exitst in java)

Comment: Well, shengy seemed to struggle to find an algorithm to solve the exercise, so I presented an algorithm, leaving Java implementation to him, as I thought it would be more beneficial for him education wise.

Comment: You say "this should print". Thats like "I'm not sure". How do you test pseudocode?
Anyway, I don't want debating here. :-)