# 10bit binary number from a string to a byte

Tags: java, binary

Currently I have a 8 bit binary string and I want to shift it left and get a 10bit binary number from it.
(ie 0111001010)

```
 String[] channels = datArray.get(n).split(" ");
 byte[] RI = channels[m+1].getBytes();
 String s = (Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.parseInt(channels[m+1])));
```

Example Values:

RI is equal to:  [B@4223b758

S is equal to:    1100101

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `[B@4223b758` is a useless description (it's just the memory address of the object). Show the contents of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't this work for you:

```
String input = "1100101";
int value = Integer.parseInt(input, 2) << 1;
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(value));
```

Returns:

```
11001010
```

Parsed binary string and shifted left (one digit).

The two things that it looks like you are missing from your approach are the ability to [specify a `radix`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) when parsing a String representing a binary numeral, and the [left shift operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html).

If you wanted the leading zeros I was surprised to see that there is no built in way to accomplish this, and the current wisdom is this is the optimal way (taken from [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421400/how-to-get-0-padded-binary-representation-of-an-integer-in-java))

```
System.out.println(String.format("%10s", Integer.toBinaryString(value)).replace(' ', '0'));
```

Which for the example value given would return this:

```
0011001010
```

Comment: I can see how my answer isn't that much different than @AkhileshSingh's but I think simulating bit shift operators is less clean.  To each their own :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use following:

```
BigInteger i = new BigInteger("00000011" + "00", 2);
int x = i.intValue();
```

Where "00000011" is your string representation of 8 bit number. The "00" simulates the left shifting..

Comment: Seems like a lot of work to avoid using [`<<`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)

Comment: Actually no. If we notice the question starts with a String input and not a number type. If we have to parse the String, BigInteger is not going to be lot of work.