# How to convert an integer to a binary representation that also appends a certain number of bits as needed

Tags: java, binary, int, bit

I know about `Integer.toBinaryString(int i)` , but what I am trying to decide how to do is `append a certain number of bits (0's)` to the end of it as needed.

Example: I have the `integer 3` which is represented by `11 in binary`, but I want it to be 7 digits (bits) long in total so it will get the length of the binary value (in this case 2 bits) and then add 5 0's to the start so you will finish with `0000011` for a total of `7 bits`.

Comment: If you're treating it as a string, use a loop to concatenate `"0"`s to the front of it. If you're treating this an `int`, there's no need to do any kind of manipulation; the value will remain 0x03 regardless.

Comment: You can look at this - [How to get 0-padded binary representation of an integer in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421400/how-to-get-0-padded-binary-representation-of-an-integer-in-java), looks similer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421400/how-to-get-0-padded-binary-representation-of-an-integer-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
String output= String.format("%"+numberOfZerosToPut+"s",
                  Integer.toBinaryString(3)).replace(' ', '0');

System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: Works like a charm, Thank you!!

Also, for those reading this with similar problems other than the example I used, you can change the code to be 

    String output= String.format("%"+numberOfZerosToPut+"s", Integer.toBinaryString(3)).replace(' ', '0');

And it will simply put the number of 0s necessary at the front of the binary value.

Comment: But this will work for a limited values that can be formed using 8 bits only.

Comment: @nishu, Yes, it will be work for 7 bits, As OP mentioned 7 bits to his question.

Comment: @nishu I tested it with something that only required 4 bits (integer value of 9) but I told it I needed 9 bits total and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Ok If no of bits are known.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method like this :

```
public static String appendZeroes(String bits) {
        int rem = bits.length()%8;
        if(rem == 0)
            return bits;
        else
        {
            int appendingZeroes = 8-rem;
            String s = "";
            for(int i=0;i<appendingZeroes;i++)
                s+="0";
            s=s+bits;
            return s;
        }
    }
```