# How to convert decimal to binary and format it in a specific way?

Tags: java

When using the `Integer.toBinaryString()` method to convert decimal to binary my program keeps returning the binary code without the leading 0's in the binary representation. How can I make sure that the zeros aren't lost? For example if the code is:

```
String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(84);
```

I get `1010100` instead of `01010100`

How can I make sure that the leading zero doesn't disappear ?

Comment: `String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(84)` convert decimal to binary not ascci to binary.

Comment: @Masud - Actually, it converts binary to character.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get 0-padded binary representation of an integer in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421400/how-to-get-0-padded-binary-representation-of-an-integer-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

You can format the result from the [Integer.toBinaryString(int i)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString%28int%29) method with the [String.format(String pattern, Object ... args)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) method:

```
String binaryString = Integer.toBinaryString(84);
String format = String.format("%8s", binaryString).replace(' ', '0');
```

Comment: An integer is 32 bit, this will also show the first 8 0's whereas he only wants the last 8.

Comment: Much better now, +1 :)