# Java: How to output all possible binary combinations (256 different sequences)?

Tags: java, binary

I need to create a function that outputs all possible binary combinations (2^8 == 256 different sequences of 8 bits.). I'm really stumped on this. I have to do it with nested loops, and am not sure how to go about it. Below is what I tried so far. I was told that I could write this program using 8 nested loops, each one going from 0 to 1; Also, I could try to do this with bit manipulation operators.

Although what I have below is obviously wrong, I tried my best to show that I at least tried this. I also need to put new line's after each closing bracket, to separate the output.

**The output should look like this:**

00000000

00000001

00000010

00000011

00000100

...

11111110

11111111

```
public static void outputBinary(){

int[][][][][][][][] num = new int[2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2];

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){

    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++){

    for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++){

    for (int l = 0; l < 2; l++){

    for (int m = 0; m < 2; m++){

    for (int n = 0; n < 2; n++){

    for (int o = 0; o < 2; o++){

    for (int p = 0; p < 2; p++){

        System.out.print(num[i][j][k][l][m][n][o][p]);

    } }}}}}}}
```

}

**Thanks for looking.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need for the array. Here is a slight modification to your code that will output all the permutations.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
  for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
    for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++){
      for (int l = 0; l < 2; l++){
        for (int m = 0; m < 2; m++){
          for (int n = 0; n < 2; n++){
            for (int o = 0; o < 2; o++){
              for (int p = 0; p < 2; p++){
                System.out.println("" + i + j + k + l + m + n + o + p);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Do you *have* to use nested loops? Because this is trivially easy when you simply take advantage of the fact that the binary representation of all the numbers from 0 through 255 cover every permutation.

```
for (int i=0; i<256; i++) {
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(i));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is somewhat embarrassing that I don't know how to do this, but I will make sure to study/practice it until I do. Thanks for your help.

Comment: BTW your one-liner won't be satisfactory because leading zeros are important to meet the requirement.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik To get the zero padding: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4421438/166339 . Accepted answer is kinda ugly but satisfies the requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Just print the `for` variables (`i...p`) without accessing this obscure empty array.

Comment: From the deleted answer by Asaph: `System.out.println("" + i + j + k + l + m + n + o + p);`

Answer (score 1):

Well, if it's OK to use some built-in classes, you can do this in the following way:

```
for (int i=0; i<256; i++){
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(i));
}
```

And the second way (I believe you should use it, because looking by looking at it you can understand what's under the hood instead of "some magic", it uses `bit mask`):

```
for (int i=0;i<256;i++){
    int mask = 256;
    while (mask > 0){
        if ((mask & i) == 0){
            System.out.print("0");
        } else {
            System.out.print("1");
        }
        mask = mask >> 1;
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: My instructions were: "You can use nested loops, if your familiar with how base 2 works, you can program it by extracting the base 2 digits; if you're familiar with bit manipulation operators, you could use them to output the values." I'm just trying to do it in a way that makes the most sense for me conceptually.

Comment: @user2411290 I've added the second way - it should be used in education purposes instead of "some magic", it uses bit manipulation

Answer (score 0):

Here's my version. It uses recursion to convert base 2 to base 10 through repeated division:

```
public static void printBin()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        int binary = decToBin(i, "");
        // pad to give length of 8
        System.out.println(String.format("%08d", binary));
    }
}

public static int decToBin(int dec, String bin)
{
    int quot = dec / 2;
    int remainder = dec % 2;
    if (quot == 0)
        return Integer.parseInt("" + remainder + bin);
    return decToBin(quot, "" + remainder + bin);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres another way of generating all the values using bit operations

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numBits = 8;

    int val = 0;
    int[] values = new int[]{0,1};
    values[0] = 0;
    values[1] = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i < numBits; i++) {
        int[] moreValues = new int[values.length * 2];
        int start = (int)Math.pow(2, i);
        for (int j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
            moreValues[j * 2] = values[j] << 1;
            moreValues[j * 2 + 1] = values[j] << 1 | 1;
        }
        values = moreValues;
    }

    //print the values
    for (int value: values) {
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(value));
    }

}
```

And another way, using bit operations and recursion

```
private static void generateNumbers(int number, int numBits, int currentBit) {
    if (numBits == currentBit) {
        Integer.toBinaryString(number);
        return;
    }
    currentBit++;

    generateNumbers(number << 1, numBits, currentBit);
    generateNumbers(number << 1 | 1, numBits, currentBit);

}

public static void generateNumbers(int numBits) {
    generateNumbers(0, 8, 1);
    generateNumbers(1, 8, 1);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    generateNumbers(8);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package org.cross.topology;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //System.out.println("sushil");
        int digits=3;//Provide number of digits for which you want combinations of 0 and 1
        int noof0and1=(int) Math.pow(2,digits)/*(2^digits)*/,combinations=(int) Math.pow(2,digits),secondloopcounter=0,temp=0;
        String current_char="0";
        int startindex=0,lastindex;

        ArrayList<String> al=new ArrayList<String>(combinations);
        for(int k=0;k<combinations;k++)
        {
            al.add("");
        }

        for(int i=1;i<=digits;i++)
        {
            noof0and1=noof0and1/2;
            while(temp!=combinations)
            {
                temp=temp+noof0and1;
                secondloopcounter++;
            }
            lastindex=noof0and1;
            startindex=0;
            for(int s=0;s<secondloopcounter;s++)
            {
                for(int j=startindex;j<lastindex;j++)
                {
                    String temps=al.get(j)+current_char;
                    al.remove(j);
                    al.add(j, temps);
                }

                    if(current_char.equals("0"))
                    {
                        current_char="1";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        current_char="0";
                    }
              startindex=lastindex;
              lastindex=lastindex+noof0and1;
            }

            temp=0;
            secondloopcounter=0;
        }

        for(int l=0;l<al.size();l++)
        {
            System.out.println(al.get(l));
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution using Recursion as an approach in java

```
public class NumberOfBinaryPatterns {

    static int[] bitArray = new int[]{0,1};

    public static void main(String args[])
    {   
        System.out.println("Below are the patterns\n");

        int numberOfBits=4;  // It can be any value based on the requirement, In this case we can put this as 8

        drawBinaryPattern(numberOfBits,"");
    }

    private static void drawBinaryPattern(int n,String seed)
    {
        if(n==0){
            System.out.println(seed);
            return;
        }   
        for(int j=0;j<bitArray.length;j++)
        {
            String temp = seed+bitArray[j];
            drawBinaryPattern(n-1,temp);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Do in php , very easy
Just convert every count of combinations in binary and add as many 0 as required to complete it in a byte representation.

```
    for($c=1;$c<=pow(2,8);$c++)
    {
      $bin_str=base_convert($c,10,2);   //converting combination number into binary string
      $len_str=strlen($bin_str);        // Length of string obtained
      for($i=1;$i<=8-$len_str;$i++)
        $bin_str="0".$bin_str;      // adding as many 0 as required to complete in byte format

      echo "<br>".$bin_str;         //Displaying binary values in byte structure

  }
```