# BigInteger's "&" Logical Operator Equivalent

Tags: java, if-statement, biginteger

I have this code:

```
if ((x & y)==0){ 
// do this... 
}
```

I would like to achieve the same effect but using BigInteger instead of int.

I tried this:

```
if ((x.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO)==0)&&(y.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO)==0)){ 
// do this...
}
```

Now, however, my program is never going inside this if statement. I would really appreciate your help.

Also, here's the entire code.

```
import java.math.*;

public class mew {

public static void main (String[] args) {

BigInteger two = BigInteger.valueOf(2);
BigInteger num = two.pow(100);
BigInteger i = BigInteger.valueOf(0);

while (i.compareTo(num) < 0){
    BigInteger mask = num;

    while (mask.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) > 0){
            if ((mask.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO)==0)&&(i.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO)==0)){
             System.out.print("0");
             }
            else {
             System.out.print("1");
                }
             mask = mask.shiftRight(1);
                }
     System.out.println();
     i = i.add(BigInteger.valueOf(1));
          }

    }
}
```

The purpose is to print all possible permutations of an n-long bit string. I ought to reference where I got the idea and the implementation: [Java: How to output all possible binary combinations (256 different sequences)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22208514/java-how-to-output-all-possible-binary-combinations-256-different-sequences) see nikis post.

Comment: `int&int` is a bitwise operator, **not** a logical operator. Its equivalent is [`BigInteger.and(BigInteger)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#and(java.math.BigInteger))

Comment: `x & y == 0` does *not* mean `x == 0 && y == 0`.

Comment: Takeaway: read the JavaDoc.

Comment: Your expression using `BigInteger` isn't equivalent to your original `if ((x & y) == 0)`. The `(x & y) == 0` is **true** if `x` and `y` don't have any 1 bits in common in their binary representations. But your `BigInteger` expression is true if both the mask and the value are zero, which evidently never happens.

Answer (score 5):

The equivalent of

```
if ((x & y)==0){ 
    // do this... 
}
```

for BigInteger is

```
if (x.and(y).equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
    // do this...
}
```

Neither of these things is the same as saying "if x and y are both zero".