# Is java toBinaryString Incorrect?

Tags: java

I have this Code:

```
    String hexCode = "A1E1F1";
    int länge = hexCode.length ();
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i <= länge - 1 ; i ++) {

    char pos = hexCode.charAt(i);

        String binCode = Integer.toBinaryString(pos);

    System.out.print ( binCode);
```

When I run it I get this result:

```
100000111000110001011100011000110110001
```

Which I don't believe is correct. Shouldn't it be:

```
101000011110000111110001
```

Are these results actually the same? Why does java give me the first result?

Comment: I suggest you read the documentation for toBinaryString().  The simple solution is to parse the hex as hexidecimal and to write it as binary.  Are you required to example each character?

Comment: Note that `toBinaryString` removes leading zeros, so the actual length of the result string will vary.  Also note that `print` will be called 6 times, and the outputs will all be smashed together.  This means that it's impossible to look at the output and tell where one binary string starts and the other ends.  That's usually not what you want (but who knows, maybe it is).

Comment: I see that you were trying to output hex digits.  It still won't work, because `toBinaryString` on 1 will return `"1"`, not `"0001"`.

Comment: ProTip: If you're wondering whether a relatively straightforward method in a widely-used JDK class that has been around [since JDK 1.0.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString(int)) is incorrect -- the answer is almost always "no."

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421400/how-to-get-0-padded-binary-representation-of-an-integer-in-java for some ideas of how to format the number in binary and include leading zeros.

Answer (score 6):

You aren't parsing your input string as a HEX representation. You're taking each character, getting its `char` value and converting that to binary representation.

What you want is to parse the input text as a base 16 integer

```
String hexCode = "A1E1F1";
int val = Integer.parseInt(hexCode, 16);
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(val));
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Integer.toBinaryString is correct. Your answer is the binary of `pos` without any newlines.

```
1000001
110001
1000101
110001
1000110
110001
```

The output you expected requires you to decode the digit value. Like

```
String binCode = Integer.toBinaryString(Character.digit(pos, 16));
```

Then the output is

```
101011110111111
```

Comment: Which still isn't what he wants--I think he wants a four-character string for every hex digit.  Thus `toBinaryString` won't work since it strips leading zeroes.