# Converting 4 different integers into a set length byte arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to convert 4 integers from a text file and convert and assign them into a byte array of 26 bytes.

Ex. Text file contains numbers `1` `8` `113` `4` and these four integers are to be placed in this exact sequence consecutively:

```
001 01000 0001110001 00000100
```

To further reiterate I want to have 4 bytes set and put an int into, so instead of outputting 2 like this

```
10
```

I want it like

```
0010
```

Edit: Basically for the example above I just want 4 different byte arrays that have a set length of 3, 5, etc and want to insert an int into each array. Sorry for making it confusing.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - Do you at least understand what exactly OP is asking for? I don't.

Comment: Why 26 bytes? @monsterbasher

Comment: @PM77-1 Like why each `int` should have a different binary width?

Comment: You are being somewhat inconsistent here, regarding the format of the numbers. What if all 4 numbers are 255s? At best, you can write 255 as 11111111, which is 8 binary digits, times 4 is 32. Also, you mention byte array of 26 bytes, which is not consistent with your exammple, because your example has 26 bits

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yeah exactly. I'm confused.

Comment: Well i'm currently trying to encode a genetic algorithm chromosome and a gene represents each part of the binary string I showed above. And one chromosome represents all those genes combined into a 26 bit string.

Comment: But your question asks about `int` (a 4 byte datatype) and `byte` (an 8 bit datatype), nothing in your question gives us any clue as to how or why each field should be at each length. You can always write a function to pad your `String` value with leading zeros. A binary string is **not** a byte array.

Comment: Blah I asked it really weird, I just want to convert an int into a byte array with the leading zeroes added.

Comment: So just to clarify - you want each byte in your byte array to be either 00000000 or 00000001, right?  You're only using one bit from each byte?

Comment: Yeah, I messed up on my part, I'm terribly inexperienced with programming mind you. So I want to convert a int value into it's bit counterpart but have it so there's a set amount of bits.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Please use the close reason made for this type of question, i.e. "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers"

Comment: Awfully similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/4421400

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, you could start by writing a function to pad a `String` with a leading character. Something like

```
public static String padString(String in, char padChar, int length) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length);
    sb.append(in);
    for (int i = in.length(); i < length; i++) {
        sb.insert(0, padChar);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Then you could call [`Integer.toBinaryString(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString%28int%29) and pass the result to `padString` like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(padString(Integer.toBinaryString(2), '0', 4));
}
```

Output is (as requested)

```
0010
```

Comment: ... or use the perfectly good `leftPad` method in the Apache commons `StringUtils` class, or something like it.  No point in re-inventing wheels.

Comment: @DavidWallace Apache Commons has a lot of high value code in it. But I try to avoid writing answers using third party code unless it has been asked for explicitly in the question.

Comment: It's a shame that you avoid doing that, Elliott, because it means you're missing out on teaching people one of the most valuable lessons of software development - that is, don't repeat someone else's work.

Comment: @DavidWallace Perhaps, but introducing a third-party dependency can cause [issues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell). Further, [`StringUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) is part of [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) and it seems like overkill to add an entire library for one function.

Comment: Couldn't agree less - which means maybe it's time for me to write my own answer!

Comment: @DavidWallace You probably could agree less, I could say something rude, untrue or disparaging about Apache Commons. You can always write your own answer, but don't reinvent the wheel isn't really an answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using padding, you can achieve something like the following. `String.format("%0{n}d", number)` will not work here since the bitstring is not an integer and you can only prepend/append spaces to a string.

### Output

```
0000001
0001000
1110001
0000100
```

### Code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] values = { 1, 8, 113, 4 };
        int width = -getMaxWidth(values);

        for (int value : values) {
            System.out.println(prettyPrintBitString(value, width));
        }
    }

    public static String prettyPrintBitString(int value, int padding) {
        return pad(Integer.toBinaryString(value), '0', padding);
    }

    public static int getMaxWidth(int[] values) {
        return numberOfBits(Collections.max(toList(values)));
    }

    public static int numberOfBits(int value) {
        return (int) (Math.floor(Math.log(value) / Math.log(2)) + 1);
    }

    public static List<Integer> toList(int[] values) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int value : values) list.add(value);
        return list;
    }

    public static String pad(String str, char token, int count) {
        StringBuilder padded = new StringBuilder(str);
        if (count < 0) {
            while (padded.length() < -count) padded.insert(0, token);
        } else if (count > 0) {
            while (padded.length() < count) padded.append(token);
        }
        return padded.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't use `StringBuffer`.

Comment: My bad, I know about the asynchronous nature of it. I just imported  it quickly.