# Why Stringbuilder is displaying output like this.[000000[I@232204a1[I@232204a1[I@232204a1[I@232204a1]

Tags: java, bit, stringbuilder

I am trying to convert int into bits of specified length and storing them using StringBuilder. But my output is not the string of bits instead shows some random data.
 I took reference from this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27737240/10494810

```
 static StringBuilder final_string = new StringBuilder();
public static void main (String[] args) {
    int[] values = {2,4,7,8};
    int[] length = {8,10,10,7};
    appendString(values, '0', length);
}

public static void appendString(int[] in, char padChar, int[] length) {
    for(int j = 0; j< in.length;j++){
       String temp =Integer.toBinaryString(in[j]);
        int temp_length = length[j];
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(temp_length);
          sb.append(in);
            for (int i = temp.length(); i < temp_length; i++) {
             sb.insert(0, padChar);
             }
            final_string.append(sb);
   }
   System.out.println((final_string.toString()));
```

}

Output of the Above code is:
000000[I@232204a1[I@232204a1[I@232204a1[I@232204a1

Expected output is:
00000010 0000000100 0000000111 0001000

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Two errors:

**1**. `sb.append(in);`

You are appending the whole array, that means only the address (@xxxxxx) to the compiler. Did you mean `sb.append(in[j]);` ?

**2**. `final_string.append(sb);`

You can't append a StringBuilder to another the way you are assuming. This way you are actually using [StringBuilder append(Object obj)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append(java.lang.Object)), so it only appends it as an object, again that means as an address or stuff like this. Consider using `final_string.append(sb.toString());` or `final_string.append(sb.substring(0));` instead.

Hope I helped

Comment: Glad I helped! Did you use `toString` or `substring`? Or was it just `in[j]` ?

Comment: `@xxxxxxx` is not the address, and the compiler is not present at this time.