# Hexadecimal to Binary Error Java

Tags: java, binary, hex

I am trying to convert hexadecimal to Binary but the problem is the result is ignoring the zeroes which I should get on the left hand side which are crucial for me.

My code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner scan;
    int num;

    System.out.println("HexaDecimal to Binary");
    scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("\nEnter the number :");
    num = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine(), 16);

    String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(num);

    System.out.println("Binary Value is : " + binary);

}
```

OUTPUT :
When I am giving the input as `0000000000001a000d00` I should get the output as

```
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011010000000000000110100000000
```

But Instead I get `11010000000000000110100000000` leaving the initial zeroes.

How should I get the exact number.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The number you get *is* the exact number; leading zeroes have no effect in a positional number system.

Comment: @hexafraction I need the leading zeroes as I have to do the xor operation

Comment: Xor doesn't require the numbers are in a string. You can just use var1^var2, where the two variables are numeric types. You may need to use a big integer in the case of very large numbers, however.

Comment: @hexafraction I am using xor cipher in which I need to get the xor by taking each single character in the binary value. How can I get the leading zeroes for that because without it my answer will be different.

Comment: You may find this link here useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421400/how-to-get-0-padded-binary-representation-of-an-integer-in-java

Comment: @JohnH in the link the person knows the number of zeroes he must get. Here I don't know the input so I cannot add as many zeroes, what I am doing is for each initial zero I am adding 4 zeroes but again if the first digit is 1 the binary format is 0001 and therefore I miss 3 zeroes

Comment: Just for clarification, you mean that if your input contains 3 leading zeros, then your output must contain 3*5=15 leading zeros?

Answer (score 0):

You can try solution from link ([How to get 0-padded binary representation of an integer in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421400/how-to-get-0-padded-binary-representation-of-an-integer-in-java)) provided by @JohnH, combined with calculating length of binary representation of your hex number.  Each hexadecimal digit requires 4 binary digits to represent:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    Scanner scan;
    int num;

    System.out.println("HexaDecimal to Binary");
    scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("\nEnter the number :");
    String input = scan.nextLine().trim();
    num = Integer.parseInt(input, 16);

    int paddedLength = input.length() * 4;
    String binary = String.format("%"+ paddedLength +"s", Integer.toBinaryString(num)).replace(' ', '0');
    System.out.println("Binary Value is : " + binary);
}
```

It's not perfect, but should do the trick.