# How to left pad zeroes to number between 1 to 1000 while reading it from file?

Tags: java, file, properties

I have to left pad 0's while printing it on console. Here I am reading number from a file.. The code is as below:

```
public class FormatNumber {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Properties properties=new Properties();
    File newFile=new File("FormatNo.properties");
    try {
        newFile.createNewFile();
        properties.load(new FileInputStream(newFile));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String transId = properties.getProperty("TransNum");
    System.out.println(transId);
    String RegisId  = properties.getProperty("RegId");
    String R=  String.format("%02d", RegisId);
    System.out.println(R);
    String T=String.format("%04d", transId);
    System.out.println(T);  }
```

In FormatNo.properties file I am storing TransNum=6 and RegId=56. The error what I am getting is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.String
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473282/how-can-i-pad-an-integers-with-zeros-on-the-left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you specify "d" in string format as here:

```
String R=  String.format("%02d", RegisId);
```

You have to provide integer as an argument and error message is saying you that: "d != java.lang.String".

The correct version should be:

```
String R = String.format("%02d", Integer.parseInt(RegisId));
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your numbers from 0 to 1000 are in `transId` and this format in `Integer` this will format with EXACT 4 positions so `0` will be `0000` and `999` will be `0999`

```
String.format("%04d", Integer.parseInt(transId));
```

If there are problems with number formats in `transId` [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421400/how-to-get-0-padded-binary-representation-of-an-integer-in-java).