# How can I split binary into 4 bytes sections?

Tags: java

I have a char holding different characters, and I would like to print the binary value of these into two 4 bytes sections. I am adding a 1 at the beginning so that they would be 4 each.

```
    System.out.println(1 + Integer.toString(mychar[i],2));
```

I am using a for loop to go through the different characters and create a table. By doing this I can get the binary value plus the one. But i don't know how to separate it into two 4 bytes.

Lets assume that `mychar[i]` holds the String bryan. The output should be the following.

```
 b    1110 0010
 r    1111 0010
 y    1111 1001
 a    1110 0001
 n    1110 1110
```

Comment: Can you provide an example value of `mychar` and what output you'd want to get for it?

Comment: @Mureinik,@SkinnyJ, I just edited it, it didn't came out as a table but that is mainly what I want.

Comment: Why are you adding `1`? The actual value for ASCII "b" should be `01100010`.

Comment: @RealSkeptic,  I am confused I thought that the ASCII value for "b" was 98. i was adding the 1 to create a two sections of 4 bytes. Thanks for making that table for me by the way.

Comment: Yes, 98 in decimal is 64 + 32 + 2, which means `01100010`. Your output, however, adds a `1` on the left, and this indicates adding another 128.

Comment: That about using [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4421400/589259) for 8 characters, then split the string in two and add a space in the middle?

Comment: @RealSkeptic, Understood, then I guess I can just use the ASCII value and splt it in two, but I don't know how to do the splitting process. Any ideas?

Comment: These are 4 bit sections, called "nibbles", they are not bytes. They can be represented by 4 binary digits, which are characters. Characters are not bytes either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My personal favorite for zero-padding a small number (that is, a byte, a short etc) when converted to binary is:

```
String binaryRep = Integer.toBinaryString( 0x100 | mychar[i] & 0xff ).substring(1);
```

- The `&` makes sure that no more than 8 bits are taken from `mychar[i]`
- The `0x100 |` part sets the 9th bit. This means all the zeros in the rightmost 8 bits will be represented in the result, which will be exactly 9 characters long.
- Then taking the substring from 1 makes sure we take just the 8.

Of course, the above assumes a character that fits into 8 bits. If you try a Chinese or Arabic character it will basically just give you its rightmost 8 bits.

Whatever method you use for producing 8 zero-padded bits, you'll need to add the space in the middle. For my method above, we can make this modification:

```
public static String eightBitCharToBinary( char c ) {

    String charAsNineBits = Integer.toBinaryString( 0x100 | c & 0xff );
    return charAsNineBits.substring(1,5) + " " + charAsNineBits.substring(5,9);

}
```

Which does the same as above, but instead of just taking one substring, takes two substrings and puts a space in the middle.

Answer (score 3):

I've used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4421438/589259) to come to a solution:

```
private static String toBinaryRepresentation(String name) {
    // 11 is size of "0000 0000\r\n
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(name.length() * 11);
    for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++) {
        String binRep = toBinaryRepresentation(name.charAt(i));
        sb.append(String.format("%s%n", binRep));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

private static String toBinaryRepresentation(char c) {
    if (c > 0xFF) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Character value too high to print");
    }
    int highNibble = (c >> 4) & 0xF;
    String highBinaryDigits = String.format("%4s", Integer.toBinaryString(highNibble)).replace(' ', '0');
    int lowNibble = c & 0xF;
    String lowBinaryDigits = String.format("%4s", Integer.toBinaryString(lowNibble)).replace(' ', '0');
    return String.format("%s %s", highBinaryDigits, lowBinaryDigits);
}
```

Which you can use by calling the function like this:

```
String name = "brian";
System.out.print(toBinaryRepresentation(name));
```

This prints:

```
0110 0010
0111 0010
0110 1001
0110 0001
0110 1110
```

So this first separates the high and low nibble and then prints the value using precisely 4 bits, even if they are zero.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static void main(String []args){

  String [] mychar = {"bryan"};
   int len = mychar.length;

  // iterate over each mychar element
  for(int i =0; i< len ; i++){

 // get the first string from array
      String s = mychar[i];
      int length = s.length();

     //iterate over the string 
        for(int j =0; j< length ; j++){
            char ch = s.charAt(j);
       String str = Integer.toBinaryString(ch);
       // print each char
       System.out.print(ch+"  :  ");
   System.out.println(str.substring(0,4)+"  "+str.substring(3) );
        }
  }


 }
```

Comment: (a) I think that `mychar` is an array of `char`, though OP was a little confusing in this regard. (b) The real issue is the fact that `toBinaryString()` doesn't always return a string of length 8. Try it for the char `'#'`.

Comment: I see, so it is limited to numbers and letters probably.

Answer (score 1):

```
char c = 'b';
        String binaryString =Integer.toBinaryString(c);
        System.out.println("1" + binaryString.substring(0, 3) + "  " + binaryString.substring(3));
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. Imparting the underlying logic is more important than just giving the code, because it helps the OP and other readers fix this and similar issues themselves.

Comment: char c = 'b';Integer.toBinaryString(c)

Comment: Integer.toBinaryString(c);   gives string representation of bynarycode which is 7 digit number in this case. In println we prefix with "1' then concatenate first three digit . Then space and remaining 4 digit