# Need help reading bytes from a file (incorrect bytes returned)

Tags: java, arrays, byte, mp3, id3

i am trying to create a simple program to edit MP3 tags.But the problem is i am stuck at the very first step,as i cannot even pass the file bytes into a byte array.Technically i can,but they are wrong.

For example,if i copy the bytes into a txt file and open it,most of the text is gibberish including the tags(a problem for later),but the first letters are ID3 which are correct.

But if i print the byte array that results from the mp3 in the console,the first values are

1001001
1000100
110011
11
0
0
.....
Which are all invalid characters.But add a zero before the first row,a zero before the second,and TWO zeroes before the third and it now says ID3

What would cause zeroes to get lost like that? It's the same for every mp3 file.Thank you in advance for any help

The piece of code is a very simple copy

try {

```
            FileInputStream BF1 = new FileInputStream("test.mp3");
            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("byteresults.txt");
            byte[] tempbyte = new byte[1024];
            BF1.read(tempbyte);
            BF1.close();





             int i;
             for(i=0;i<900;i++){
             System.out.print(Integer.toBinaryString(tempbyte[i])+'\n');}



        } catch(FileNotFoundException fnf)
        {
                System.out.println("Specified file not found :" + fnf);
        }
        catch(IOException ioe)
        {
                System.out.println("Error while copying file :" + ioe);
        }
```

Comment: Those 3 bytes match decimal values 73, 68, and 51. Converted to ASCII characters it is "ID3" as expected.

Comment: but they are 7 bits.i need to put a number of zeroes in front of each to appear as a number.Also wtf kind of bit is 11? That doesn't correspond to any ASCII character

Comment: Interesting... I've never used that method before but it does look like you have to pad the front of the bytes with any missing 0's. I did find a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421400/how-to-get-0-padded-binary-representation-of-an-integer-in-java though that will pad the result.

Comment: well thank you for the help,i added the padding but umm there are many bytes that do not make sense.Some programs made to read mp3 tags read them fine,as do the windows properties,but if i dump the header bytes into a text file only couple of words are distinguishable

Comment: There are no guarantees regarding how many bytes are actually read by `BF1.read(tempbyte)`.  That’s why the method returns a value that tells you.  You should probably pay attention to it.

Comment: could you explain what do you mean by that? if it reads more bytes than the tempbyte size,they are lost,but the first 30-40 of them should be intact no?

Answer (score 0):

When printing Binary format, most systems drop the leading zeroes since they do not contribute to the final value. You only expect eight digits cos it's bytes but **binary counting** itself doesn't work like that. It doesnt care for 8 slots or 4 slots etc. Consider `3` is written as `11` in binary so why bother printing that as `00000011`?? Why not `0011`?? The human reader will ignore those leading zeroes anyway.

Maybe you could try Hex format as it easier (= more efficiency). Something like :

```
for ( i=0; i<900; i++)
{
    //System.out.print(Integer.toBinaryString(tempbyte[i])+'\n');
    System.out.printf("0x%02X", tempbyte[i]);
}
```

This way you can even check your output against some Hex Editor software (handling exact same file's bytes). Easier to check that you have the right bytes at right place with right values etc...