# Any string value to binary conversion in Java

Tags: java, javafx

I have a code to convert anyway English alphabetical value to binary code (a --> 01100001). The code is working fine with one exception. when the result appears after conversion, it is missing a "0" in the front. Ex: a --> 1100001. It does this regardless of either capital of lowercase letter.

Why is it doing that? All I need is 0 in the front.
Reference: http://www.convertbinary.com/alphabet/

Note: the string value (user first name) is input by the end user, not in the code it self as some threads on here about conversion shows.

```
public class ConversionController {

/**
 * The getBinaryName is used to convert string to binary form
 * 
 * @param name
 *            to be converted
 * @return converted binary name
 */
 public String getBinaryName(String name) {

    if (name == null || name.isEmpty()) {
        return "";
    }

    String result = "";
    char[] messChar = name.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < messChar.length; i++) {
        result += Integer.toBinaryString(messChar[i]) + " ";
    }

    return result;
}

}
```

SOLUTION: added "0" in front of the conversion result. 
    result+= "0" +Integer.toBinaryString(messChar[i]) + " ";

Comment: It seems to me that the first thing you need to consider is what encoding you want to use. What would you want the output to be for  for example?

Comment: Your problem is that you need padding. See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421400/how-to-get-0-padded-binary-representation-of-an-integer-in-java

Comment: Jon: probably :-)

Comment: Why do *you* think your code should add a 0 at the front? Does the javadoc of Integer.toBinaryString say that it does that? When I read the javadoc, I see *with no extra leading 0s*. So why are you expecting a leading zero?

Comment: There is no need of leading zeros that is why `Integer.toBinaryString()` returns a String without leading zeros. So you will always get a binary string starting with `1`. I think you here need a `Binary String` of fixed length `8`. You can do here padding which fits the ouput in `8` length string with leading zeros as pad. But you require to do this for alphabets only as you have mentioned and all Unicode's of Alphabets use only 7 bits so you can simply add "0" before every output.

Comment: @SanketMakani Thanks, that's exactly what I did. I noticed your last name, curious if you're Ismaili.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
    public String getBinaryName(String name) {
    String initial;
    int size = 8;

    if (name == null || name.isEmpty()) {
        return "";
    }

    String result = "";
    char[] messChar = name.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < messChar.length; i++) {
        initial = Integer.toBinaryString(messChar[i]);
        int times = size - initial.length();
        for(int x = 0; x < times; x++) {
            result += "0";
        }
        result += initial;
    }

    return result;
}
```

I just put the local variable *size* to 8 as a convenience. But it could be set to what you want and perhaps through an argument in the method.
size equals how long you want it to be. 8 meaning 8-bits = 1 byte.

As stated by JB Nizet Integer.toBinaryString doesnt add leading 0's. It truncates it to the most significant bit. 
0000 1001 becomes 1001, 
0001 0001 becomes 10001
etc.

size - initial.length() checks the difference between this truncated length and the length that you want with leading zero's. That difference is then used with the variable named *times* to make an internal loop add zero's that many times before appending the truncated part.