# Converting int 0 to binary in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am converting 4 integers into binary and everything works fine until it has to convert a zero.

for example:

```
int subnet1 = 255;
int subnet2 = 255;
int subnet3 = 255;
int subnet4 = 0;

binarystring = Integer.toBinaryString(subnet1) 
+ Integer.toBinaryString(subnet2)
+ Integer.toBinaryString(subnet3)
+ Integer.toBinaryString(subnet4);

BinaryView.setText(binarystring);
```

text would look like this: 11111111 11111111 11111111 0  (without the space inbetween)

why wont it convert the 0 to 00000000 ??

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421400/how-to-get-0-padded-binary-representation-of-an-integer-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because value for `"0000000"` is same for `"0"` that's why it set as `"0"`.

If you want to print that result. Just make a string of `"0000000"` for printing. Because int value always convert it.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the documentation here: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString(int)

It tells you:

> The unsigned integer value is the argument plus 232 if the argument is negative; otherwise it is equal to the argument. This value is converted to a string of ASCII digits in binary (base 2) **with no extra leading 0**s.

Answer (score 0):

Why?  *By design*.  From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString(int)):

> This value is converted to a string of ASCII digits in binary (base 2) **with no extra leading 0s**.

(Emphasis added.)

If you want 8 characters, append the result to a string of 7 zeros, and take the last 8 characters.  In pseudo code:

```
intermediateString = "0000000" + Integer.toBinaryString( 0 ); // obviously don't hard code zero; just for example
finalString = intermediateString.substring( intermediateString.length() - 8);
```